# C/C++ need a clever way to track function calls

Tags: c++, c, gdb, c-preprocessor

I am looking for a clever way to track function calls and returns.
I know I can use the debugger, but I would like a way to just have it print something out to the terminal when calling a function vs having to step through code.
I am thinking that I might be able to use the preprocessor, but I am not sure what would be the best way to go about this.
Or is there a way to use gdb to print out the information that would be useful, while not having to step through the code.

Answer (score 21):

Most compilers allow you to inject an instrumentation function before and after the function call.

In MSVC they are `_penter` and `_pexit`. A nice article: http://www.drdobbs.com/184403601.

In GCC you would use the `-finstrument-functions` option, see [the docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html).

You can use debug libaries or map files to get more info.

Comment: You would not happen tp know how to look up the function in the symbol table in gcc

Comment: Do you want to find the name, or look up things like parameters etc. in the debug objects?

Comment: Just the name would be fine. #delay

Comment: [link](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-generate-custom-application-profile-timelines-nvtx/) Dl_info this_fn_info; dladdr( this_fn, &this_fn_info );

Comment: @DanielMoodie There is a "call site" parameter, can I use this to find the file and line number the call was made from, e.g. \__FILE\__ and \__LINE\__?

Answer (score 7):

A quite intrussive solution is using RAII to control the scope of the function. This will have a great impact in performance, but will be quite explicit in the logs without requiring the user to add instrumentation in all possible code paths that may leave the function:

```
class ScopeLogger {
public:
   ScopeLogger( std::string const & msg ) : msg(msg)
   {   std::cout << "Enter: " << msg << std::endl; }
   ~ScopeLogger()
   {   std::cout << "Exit:  " << msg << std::endl; }
   std::string msg;
};
#if DEBUG
#define FUNCTION(x) ScopeLogger l_##x##_scope(x);
#endif

void foo( int value ) {
   FUNCTION( __FUNCTION__ );
   if ( value > 10 ) throw std::exception;
   std::cout << "." << std::endl;
}

int main() {
   foo(0);    // Enter: foo\n.\nExit:  foo
   foo(100);  // Enter: foo\nExit:  foo
}
```

If the code is single threaded, you might even want to add a static variable with some indentation level to `ScopedLogger` without adding too much to the already heavy performance impact:

```
class ScopeLogger {
public:
   ScopeLogger( std::string const & msg ) : msg(msg)
   {   std::cout << std::string(indent++,' ') << "Enter: " << msg << std::endl; }
   ~ScopeLogger()
   {   std::cout << std::string(--indent,' ') << "Exit:  " << msg << std::endl; }
   std::string msg;
   static int indent;
};
int ScopeLogger::indent = 0;
```

Comment: Quite intrusive, but less than Praveen's.

Comment: Does your code compile?  Where is the contructor for `std::string` to make this `std::string(indent++," ")` valid?

Comment: @bruce.banner: Good catch, that's what happens when you type into a webpage rather than in an editor and compile. The second argument *must be* a `char`, not a `char*` (i.e. I mistakenly had double quotes where single quotes were required). At any rate, use this just as an idea, the code has other issues, including but probably not limited to thread safety (or the lack of it).

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using GCC, you can also use linker function wrapping.

```
Link-Time Replacement / Wrapping
– GCC option: -Wl,--wrap,function_name
```

Basically, you can take a function called "function_name()" and wrap it with a function called "__wrap_function_name()".  You can access the original function by calling "__real_function_name()".

Answer (score 3):

```
#define BEGIN_FUNC(X) printf("Function %s Entered",X)
#define END_FUNC(X)  printf("Function %s End",X)

foo()
{
BEGIN_FUNC(__func__);

//Your code here


END_FUNC(__func__);


}
```

I think if you write a macro like above and use it for every function as described then you can get the logs on the terminal.

Comment: This is quite fragile. If you are programming c++, you are better off writing a small scope logger that will log on construction and on object destruction. Else you might see functions that are entered and never returned from if exceptions are thrown or if the user forgets to write the `END_FUC` macro in any returning code path.

Comment: Will it not help in debugging by seeing the logs? The OP stated any method to know call stack without using debugger. We can use this on every API of the executable and hence get the stack at any point of time.

Comment: @Nyan- I think its implied when we say start and end of function calls that it has to be added before every return.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at [Valgrind's Callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) which can track function calls into a pretty graph.  It will show function calls, but not the parameter or return values.

Answer (score 2):

> Or is there a way to use gdb to print out the information that would be useful, while not having to step through the code

Yes. Set a breakpoint only at the functions that you actually care about. Use "continue" until you get to those functions or until your program crashes. Then use "backtrace" (or "bt") to get a stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to automate it, you might take a look at `TARGET_ASM_FUNCTION_END_PROLOGUE` and `TARGET_ASM_FUNCTION_BEGIN_EPILOGUE`. These are compiler hooks that will let you specify pieces of assembly to be emitted along with the normal function prologue/epilogue -- in your case, you'd use them to emit a little assembly to log the entry/exit from the function in question. You could also look at `FUNCTION_PROFILE` and/or `PROFILE_HOOK` (e.g., at: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Function-Entry.html).

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example illustrating the GCC side of [the answer by Jonathan Fischoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3315327/673852).

Here we call external tool `addr2line` to print the location as `functionName at /path/to/file.cpp:line` instead of simply the address. I've tried using `dladdr` for this (as suggested in a comment to the answer linked above), but it returned only null pointers in `dli_sname` for me.

This approach of resolving the addresses has some drawbacks:

- It's slow due to `fork`/`execve`/file read.
- It needs exact file path to the binary containing the address, so the simple code below can't print symbols in shared libraries.

```
// Instrumentation
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void __attribute__((no_instrument_function))
    log_func(const void* funcAddr, const char* action, const void* callSite)
{
    char cmd[50];
    snprintf(cmd, sizeof cmd, "addr2line -Cpfe /proc/%d/exe %p", getpid(), funcAddr);
    fprintf(stderr, "%p %s %p ", callSite, action, funcAddr);
    system(cmd);
}

extern "C" void __attribute__((no_instrument_function))
    __cyg_profile_func_enter(void* this_fn, void* call_site)
{
    log_func(this_fn, "->", call_site);
}

extern "C" void __attribute__((no_instrument_function))
    __cyg_profile_func_exit(void* this_fn, void* call_site)
{
    log_func(this_fn, "<-", call_site);
}

// Actual code we're tracing
#include <iostream>

struct Test
{
    Test() { std::cout << "Hi, I'm Test constructor\n"; }
    void method() const { std::cout << "And I'm Test method\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, my name is main\n";
    Test test;
    test.method();
}
```

Compilation and running:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -o test -g -finstrument-functions && time ./test
0x8048b0b -> 0x804899b _GLOBAL__sub_I___cyg_profile_func_enter at /tmp/test.cpp:41
0x80489c4 -> 0x804890b __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) at /tmp/test.cpp:41
0x80489c4 <- 0x804890b __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) at /tmp/test.cpp:41
0x8048b0b <- 0x804899b _GLOBAL__sub_I___cyg_profile_func_enter at /tmp/test.cpp:41
0xf7a0de71 -> 0x804886a main at /tmp/test.cpp:37
Hello, my name is main
0x80488b1 -> 0x80489de Test::Test() at /tmp/test.cpp:32
Hi, I'm Test constructor
0x80488b1 <- 0x80489de Test::Test() at /tmp/test.cpp:32
0x80488c0 -> 0x8048a4a Test::method() const at /tmp/test.cpp:33
And I'm Test method
0x80488c0 <- 0x8048a4a Test::method() const at /tmp/test.cpp:33
0xf7a0de71 <- 0x804886a main at /tmp/test.cpp:37

real    0m0.062s
user    0m0.054s
sys     0m0.008s
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `__FUNCTION__` [(Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.80).aspx) macro used to determine what method (in the format `Class::Method`) you're in, but this is more of a manual process.

However, when I needed the same 'trace' information recently, I could not find a automatic method.