# log C++ class method callers (function name, line number)

Tags: c++

I have a class in my C++ code similar to the following:

```
class myClass
{
public:
  void method1(int a, int b, std::string str);
};
```

Other classes can instantiate an object from myClass and call method1.

```
void caller()
{
    obj1->method1(12, 4, "sample");
}
```

I want to log all the callers of myClass (function name, file name, line number). One possible solution is this:

```
class myClass
{
public:
  method1(int a, int b, std::string str, const char *_function = __builtin_FUNCTION(), const char *_file = __builtin_FILE(), int _line = __builtin_LINE());
};
```

which is using __builtin_xxx as default arguments. This solution has multiple shortcomings:

1. It is an ugly solution
2. __builtin_xxx is only available in gcc version > 4.8
3. We have to add three default parameters to method1
4. IDE shows the default parameters on auto-completion that are not meant to be provided by the user!

Another solution is using `__LINE__`, `__FILE__` and `__func__` that is basically very similar to the previous solution. They are not defined outside of function scope, and they should be used like this:

```
void caller()
{
    obj1->method1(12, 4, "sample", __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
}
```

[Here](https://onlinegdb.com/BJWePG0jW) is a working example for both solutions.

Is there any **better** solution to log the caller when the user calls method1 on myClass object. By a better solution I specifically mean not to change the method1's declaration by adding three more parameters!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C/C++ need a clever way to track function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315248/c-c-need-a-clever-way-to-track-function-calls)

Comment: You probably want  to clarify better...as the macro solution does not sacrifice performance...The problem with the IDE is really an IDE problem and not a C++ problem. What do you say?

Comment: If you don't care about performances, you can use the callstack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899870/print-call-stack-in-c-or-c

Answer (score 0):

Another ugly solution, but I'm using...

Use macros to automatically add `__LINE__`   `__FILE__` ...etc. things into parameters.

For example

```
#define Method(param0,param1) Method(param0,param1,__LINE__)
```

It has a lot of problem, if you want macros work as normal function, you has to do a lot of things, and it still may not works.

I use it to help me log errors.

Comment: I don't consider this answer as a better solution! I have updated my question to clarify more.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a duplicate of [Print the file name, line number and function name of a calling function - C Prog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884335/print-the-file-name-line-number-and-function-name-of-a-calling-function-c-pro)

```
I'd pass the data to the function through parameters (maybe get the help of a macro)

int info(const char *fname, int lineno, const char *fxname, ...) { /* ... */ }
int debug(const char *fname, int lineno, const char *fxname, ...) { /* ... */ }
int error(const char *fname, int lineno, const char *fxname, ...) { /* ... */ }
And to call them

info(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, ...);
debug(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, ...);
error(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, ...);
Note: __func__ is C99; gcc, in mode C89 has __FUNCTION__
```

Comment: I don't consider this answer as a better solution! I have updated my question to clarify more.