# dladdr doesn't return the function name

Tags: c, linux, elf

I'm trying to use dladdr.  It correctly locates the library, but it does not find the function name.  I can call objdump, do a little math, and get the address of the function that I pass dladdr.  If objdump can see it, why can't dladdr?

Here is my function:

```
const char *FuncName(const void *pFunc)
{
Dl_info  DlInfo;
int  nRet;

    // Lookup the name of the function given the function pointer
    if ((nRet = dladdr(pFunc, &DlInfo)) != 0)
        return DlInfo.dli_sname;
    return NULL;
}
```

Here is a gdb transcript showing what I get.

```
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
[Switching to Thread 0xf7f4c6c0 (LWP 28365)]
0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) p MatchRec8Cmp
$2 = {void (TCmp *, TWork *, TThread *)} 0xf1b62e73 <MatchRec8Cmp>
(gdb) call FuncName(MatchRec8Cmp)
$3 = 0x0
(gdb) call FuncName(0xf1b62e73)
$4 = 0x0
(gdb) b FuncName
Breakpoint 1 at 0xf44bdddb: file threads.c, line 3420.
(gdb) call FuncName(MatchRec8Cmp)

Breakpoint 1, FuncName (pFunc=0xf1b62e73) at threads.c:3420
3420    {
The program being debugged stopped while in a function called from GDB.
When the function (FuncName) is done executing, GDB will silently
stop (instead of continuing to evaluate the expression containing
the function call).
(gdb) s
3426            if ((nRet = dladdr(pFunc, &DlInfo)) != 0)
(gdb) 
3427                    return DlInfo.dli_sname;
(gdb) p DlInfo 
$5 = {dli_fname = 0x8302e08 "/xxx/libdata.so", dli_fbase = 0xf1a43000, dli_sname = 0x0, dli_saddr = 0x0}
(gdb) p nRet
$6 = 1
(gdb) p MatchRec8Cmp - 0xf1a43000
$7 = (void (*)(TCmp *, TWork *, TThread *)) 0x11fe73
(gdb) q
The program is running.  Exit anyway? (y or n) y
```

Here is what I get from objdmp

```
$ objdump --syms /xxx/libdata.so | grep MatchRec8Cmp
0011fe73 l     F .text  00000a98              MatchRec8Cmp
```

Sure enough, 0011fe73 = MatchRec8Cmp - 0xf1a43000.  Anyone know why dladdr can't return dli_sname = "MatchRec8Cmp" ???

I'm running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga).  I have seen this work before.  Maybe it's my compile switches:

```
CFLAGS = -m32 -march=i686 -msse3 -ggdb3 -pipe -fno-common -fomit-frame-pointer \
        -Ispio -fms-extensions  -Wmissing-declarations -Wstrict-prototypes -Wunused  -Wall \
        -Wno-multichar -Wdisabled-optimization -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs \
        -Wpointer-arith -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-sequence-point \
        -I../../../include -I/usr/local/include -fPIC \
        -D$(Uname) -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE
```

I have tried it with -g instead of -ggdb3 although I don't think debugging symbols have anything to do with elf.

Comment: Just a guess - try to `extern "C"` your MatchRec8Cmp()?

Comment: Worth a try, cept I don't think the names looked mangled when I did objdump and the funcs are in .c files.

Comment: Did you pass `-rdynamic` at linking time of your executable?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `-rdynamic` is unlikely to help: it's the default when linking a shared library anyway.

Comment: I was talking of `-rdynamic` for the program executable (and it is not the default in that case) - not for shared libraries.

Comment: -fomit-frame-pointer didn't work. :(

Comment: I also tried -fpic instead of -fPIC.  That didn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> If objdump can see it, why can't dladdr

`dladdr` can only see functions *exported* in the dynamic symbol table. Most likely

```
 nm -D /xxx/libdata.so | grep MatchRec8Cmp
```

shows nothing. Indeed your objdump shows that the symbol is *local*, which proves that this is the cause.

The symbol is local either because it has a hidden visibility, is static, or because you hide it in some other way (e.g. with a linker script).

Update:

> Those marked with the 'U' work with dladdr. They get "exported" automatically somehow.

They work because they are exported from *some other shared library*. The `U` stands for unresolved, i.e. defined elsewhere.

**Update 2023/05/14:**

I see that there are a few "answers" below which tell you to add `-rdynamic` or `--export-dynamic` to "solve" the problem.

These answers don't explain the "why" (i.e. they aren't an actual answer to the question that was asked), and also don't explain the cost of the solution, which could be significant.

First, adding `-rdynamic` flag is preferable, because that is a the compiler front-end flag, which gets translated into *appropriate* linker flag (some linkers understand `-E`, some understand `--export-dynamic`, some understand both).

Second, if you are going to add a linker-specific flag, you should do it *correctly*: `-Wl,--export-dynamic`. Adding `--export-dynamic` without `-Wl,` prefix *happens to work* by accident -- GCC doesn't understand that flag and passes it to the linker. But it may do something else in the future.

---

What are the *costs* of `-rdynamic`? It slows down your executable loading. How much of a slowdown you'll get depends on how large `nm -D a.out` becomes, compared to the same without the flag.

All the additional symbols are entered into the loader scope, and are searched whenever a symbol in a shared library needs to be resolved.

This can also break your executable if the symbol you *didn't want* to be exported becomes exported.

---

Are there better solutions than `-rdynamic`?

Glad you asked. There *probably* are.

Newer versions of the linker have `--export-dynamic-symbol SYMBOL` and `--export-dynamic-symbol-list FILE` options (do use `-Wl,` prefix if you are going to pass these flags to GCC), which allow you to control *exactly* which symbols are exported.

That is a much more precise solution (compared to `-rdynamic` which exports *everything*), and the cost is (usually) significantly lower.

Comment: You are correct in that the function in question does not show up when I do nm -D.  In fact a small random sampling of my functions is returned when I call nm.  When I pass the address of a function that does show up, dladdr works.  What I can't figure out is how to export the function.  I don't use -fvisibility, so by default all functions should be exported.  I tried using __attribute__ ((visibility("default"))), but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I hunted around for a long time and found a bash script being executed in the build which set a make variable which resulted in a --version-script being added to the build.  However for some reason, there are a number of functions that show up in the nm -D result that are not listed in the --version-script.  They all look like this: "         U MemInfoTransCreate", whereas the items in the --version-script that are marked as "global", look like this: "00000000001202ff T MatchRec8Cmp_th".   Those marked with the 'U' work with dladdr.  They get "exported" automatically somehow.

Answer (score 5):

I added `-rdynamic` to my LDFLAGS.

`man gcc` says:

```
-rdynamic
    Pass the flag -export-dynamic to the ELF linker, on targets that support it. This instructs the linker to add all symbols, not only used ones, to the
    dynamic symbol table. This option is needed for some uses of "dlopen" or to allow obtaining backtraces from within a program.
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding the gcc option "-export-dynamic" solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

hinesmr solution worked for me. The exact option I passed gcc was "-Wl,--export-dynamic" and all the functions became visible to dladdr