# Get name of calling function, line number and file name in c++

Tags: c++, error-logging

I have wrote following code to write logs in my log file.
This code is working fine for logging messages but now i have to integrate this in multiple files i need file path of caller, caller function name and line number.

Kindly help me to achieve this .

```
#include "Source.h"

bool CLogManager::fileOpenError = false;
std::string CLogManager::logFileName = "";
CLogManager* CLogManager::logManager = NULL;
FILE* CLogManager::file = NULL;

CLogManager :: CLogManager(){}
CLogManager :: ~CLogManager()
{
    if (file)
        fclose(file);
}
CLogManager* CLogManager::getInstance()
{
    if(logManager==NULL)
    {
        logManager = new CLogManager();
        logFileName = currentDateTime();
    }
    return logManager;
}
const std::string CLogManager::currentDateTime()
{
    time_t now = time(0);
    char currTime[30];
    strftime(currTime, sizeof(currTime), "Log_%Y_%m_%dT%H_%M_%S.xml", localtime(&now));
    return currTime;
}
void CLogManager::Log (char *message)
{
    file = fopen(logFileName.c_str(), "a+");
    if(file == NULL) 
    {
        if(fileOpenError == false)
        {
            std::cout << "There was an error While opening Log File."<<std::endl;
            fileOpenError = true;
        }
        return;
    }
    fputs(message, file);
    fputs("\n", file);
}

int main ()
{
    CLogManager::getInstance();
    CLogManager::Log("Sorry some error occured");
    CLogManager::Log("Please try again");
    CLogManager::Log("Wait");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: y not use log4net for logging instead of creating your own class? log4net would provide you the function name and few other details as well. not sure about the line number. You can make a dll from Log4net C# and use it in your C++ code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597078/file-line-and-function-usage-in-c

Comment: The only way I know to do this is using macros. Something like: : `#define log(msg) CLogManager::Log(std::string(msg) + " " + __FILE__ + "[" + std::to_string(__LINE__) + "]")`.

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353180/how-do-i-find-the-name-of-the-calling-function
to get the function name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I need a fast "printf" logging, I use this marco for message logging that is branded with filename and line:

```
#define _MSG(msg) do{ std::cerr << __FILE__ << "(@" << __LINE__ << "): " << msg << '\n'; } while( false )
```

The above macro will inject a `msg` into a `std::cerr` pipeline. You can take out parts you need or modify it for your purposes. It hinges on `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros, which are defined by standard:

> `__FILE__`
>   The presumed name of the current source file (a character string literal).
>
> `__LINE__`
>   The presumed line number (within the current source file) of the current source line (an integer
>   constant).

Function names are not so easy to get, and I don't think there is a nice way to get it.

If you want logging through functions I would define some macro, or make function that would take `int` and `char*` for line and file respectively. Something like `log(int line, char* source_file, string message)`.

Comment: Can you please help me how to incorporate this macro in my code?

Answer (score 5):

Since C++ 20, you can use `std::source_location`.

From the example on [CPPReference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <source_location>
 
void log(const std::string_view message,
         const std::source_location location = 
               std::source_location::current())
{
    std::cout << "file: "
              << location.file_name() << "("
              << location.line() << ":"
              << location.column() << ") `"
              << location.function_name() << "`: "
              << message << '\n';
}
 
template <typename T> void fun(T x)
{
    log(x);
}
 
int main(int, char*[])
{
    log("Hello world!");
    fun("Hello C++20!");
}
```

Output:

```
file: main.cpp(23:8) `int main(int, char**)`: Hello world!
file: main.cpp(18:8) `void fun(T) [with T = const char*]`: Hello C++20!
```

Answer (score 1):

To utilize the LogManager class that you already have written, you could do something like this:

```
void CLogManager::Log(char *message, std::string FileName = "Unset", std::string FunctionName = "Unset", int LineNumber = -1)
{
...
}
```

Then, anywhere you want to use your Logging function as it is right now, you would just do:

```
::Log(message);
```

But, if you wanted to include File/Function/Line information, you would do this:

```
::Log(message, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
```

You can adjust the defaults from "Unset" to anything you wanted (including just "").   I might also suggest in that function that you could have the output be different based upon whether the FileName parameter (passed to the function) is the default or not.  That way your log file would look clean.