# Is there MSVC equivalent for __builtin__FUNCTION()?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43970783/4806882) we can find the name of the calling function using `__builtin__FUNCTION()` in GCC. Is there MSVC equivalent for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/source_location)
 will be the cross platform solution in the future allowing you to do:

```
void log(const std::string& message, const std::experimental::source_location& location = std::experimental::source_location::current())
{
    std::cout << location.function_name() << ": " << message << "\n";
}

int main()
{
   log("test");
}
```

Until this is available the best solution I am aware of is to use macros to capture the value of `__FUNCTION__` and pass it to your function. For example something like this:

```
void log(const std::string& message, const std::string& function)
{
}

#define LOG(message) log(message, __FUNCTION__)

int main()
{
  LOG("test");
}
```

Comment: `__builtin_FUNCTION` is GCC support for `source_location` implementation! That is a really funny answer for a direct question!

Comment: @Oliv sorry I don't understand your comment? The OP was looking for a visual studio solution

Comment: Do you mean  source_location is implemented in MSVC?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, such intrinsics (`__builtin_FILE()`, `__builtin_FUNCTION()`, `__builtin_LINE()`, `__builtin_COLUMN()`) were added for VS 2019 16.6 Preview 2 (according to this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/54#issuecomment-586520516)) to support c++20 [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location).