# use different pool allocator for different class types instantiated via new() operator

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator, pool

I'm using a large third party C++ GUI toolkit in a project which uses new and delete across hundreds of classes. I want to use seperate pool allocators for specific classes in the library and I'm thinking of overriding new() and delete() to accomplish this. I know I can override the normal new operator:

```
void* operator new(std::size_t count)
```

Is there a way to know which class the operator is being called for, such that I can choose the appropriate pool to allocate from? Something like this:

```
void* operator new(std::size_t count) {  
    if (classname(caller) == "BigString") { 
        return bigStringPool.alloc(count); 
    } else if (classname(caller == "4DVector") { 
        return 4dvecPool.alloc(count); 
    } else { 
        return malloc(count); 
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The global new operator is not aware of what the memory will be used for.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I know, so the question is, how do we get around that.

Comment: You do not get around that. If you want, you can implement member `operator new` on a class-by-class basis, and implement the pool there.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux given the size and complexity of the third party framework I'm using that's going to be nearly impossible.

Comment: Then I believe what you are trying to do is nearly impossible. Consider pooling by size instead.

Comment: Beware that overloading global `operator new` in an actual application is generally not a good idea. If can be nice for instrumentation or for debugging, but it should probably not be used in production code. If you use any dependency that already overloads it, or if your software might be a dependency and someone using it tries to do the same, you may have multiple overloads. *"The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required if more than one replacement is provided in the program for any of the replaceable allocation function,"*

Comment: Does the library accept Alloc/Deleter template arguments, similar to the STL? If not, unlikely. If it does, you're golden. Look up docs for alloc/deleters.

Comment: There are some ugly tricks you can do to get the caller of a function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353180/how-do-i-find-the-name-of-the-calling-function or use a macro that replaces new with a custom allocator/placement new. Of course, if it's a precompiled library, you're out of luck.

Comment: To instrument the 3rdparty library is possible, we may write our refractor tool, then change all files automatically.

Comment: @alwaysmpe unfortunately it does not, at least not for the String class it uses all over the place. I guess I could go hack that class to get what I want.