# implement variadic log function that acquire caller's name automatically

Tags: c++

I'm using msvc, now I need a logger function that can:

1. acquire the caller's name automatically
2. can receive variadic args just like fmt::format or std::format

I tried the following:

1. use macro, it works, but it's not easy to encapsulate into a class.
2. use stacktrace library. these libraries requires pdb file but I just need embedded name strings.
3. use `std::source_location::current()`, I tried to use both `std::source_location` and template argument pack `Args&&... args` like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <source_location>
#include <format>

template<typename... Args>
    void log(const char* format_str, Args&&... args,
             const std::source_location& location = std::source_location::current()) {
    std::string func_name = location.function_name();
    std::string message = std::format(format_str, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    std::cout << "DEBUG: [" << func_name << "] " << message << '\n';
}

void someFunc() {
    log("hello {}!", "world");
}

int main() {
    someFunc();
}
```

this cannot compile, because both `Args&&... args` and default parameters should be at args list's end.

Now the only way I can do this is place `location` parameter at begin, then pass `std::source_location::current()` manually in caller function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <source_location>
#include <format>

template<typename... Args>
    void log(const std::source_location& location, const char* format_str, Args&&... args) {
    std::string func_name = location.function_name();
    std::string message = std::format(format_str, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    std::cout << "DEBUG: [" << func_name << "] " << message << '\n';
}

void someFunc() {
    log(std::source_location::current(), "hello {}!", "world");
}

int main() {
    someFunc(); // expected output: [someFunc] hello world!
}
```

this works, but I must pass "std::source_location::current()" manually at every log point, which is really verbose.

Is there anyway to automatically acquire caller's function name (or std::source_location::current()), **without** using macro?

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't copy/paste your code into a compiler and reproduce the problem.

Comment: [How do I find the name of the calling function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353180/how-do-i-find-the-name-of-the-calling-function)

Comment: @user12002570 I have rewrite my problem. The way to find the name of calling function without passing `std::source_location::current()`manually is just what I'm asking for. I'm not using macro.

Comment: You can add an overload that will explicitly pass the source location as shown [here](https://godbolt.org/z/YP43h56s3)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an overload that will explicitly pass `source_location` and forward the rest of arguments  as shown below:

```
template<typename... Args>
    void log(const std::source_location& location, const char* format_str, Args&&... args) {
    //add code here
}
//added this overload 
template<typename... Args> void log(const char* format_str, Args&&... args) {
    log(std::source_location::current(), format_str, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
void someFunc() {
    log( "hello {}!", "world");//compile now
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YP43h56s3)

Comment: this does not work because `std::source_location::current()` will acquire `log`'s function name. found solution here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547273/how-to-use-source-location-in-a-variadic-template-function)

Comment: @H3d9 Yeah, that will work. I only showed how to solve one of the problem(which was not passing sourcelocation repeatedly manually) but that did not solve the main problem which was that you wanted the caller's name.