# Error checking next node in a linked list

Tags: c, graph, linked-list

I'm trying to create a program that makes a bfs in graphs. I have created the adjacency matrix and the bfs function. The program works if I enter a small input (like 4 nodes), but if I enter bigger inputs I start getting segmentation fault.

Thing is, I don't get it always in the same place. Everytime I run it, it may crash on a different iteration, but certainly in the same loop. Here is my code:(I'm just posting the functions that I think are relevant to the problem, but if you think you need more code, just ask).

```
void matrixBfs(int n, int matrix[n][n], Node nodeLocker[n], int source)
{
    int aux;
    Box* head =(Box*) malloc(sizeof(Box*));
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory failure\n");
    }
    head->next = NULL;

    add(head, source);
    nodeLocker[source].checked = 1;

    while (len(head) > 0)
    {
        aux = pop(head);

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if ((matrix[aux][i]) && !(nodeLocker[i].checked))
            {
                add(head, i);
                nodeLocker[i].checked = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    head = NULL;
    free(head);
}
```

This is the function that crashes, and by printing I have determined that crashes either on the

> while (len(head) > 0)

and the

> add(head, i);

statements.

Those functions are:

```
// Returns the length of the list.
int len(Box* head)
{
  int i = 0;
  Box* current = head;

  for(i; current->next != NULL; i++)
  {
    current = current-> next;
  }
  return i;
}

// Adds an element at the end of the list
void add(Box* head, int value)
{
  Box* current = head;

  while((current->next) != NULL)
  {
    current = (current->next);
  }

  Box* auxNode = (Box*) malloc(sizeof(Box*));

  if (auxNode == NULL)
  {
    printf("Memory failure\n");
  }
  auxNode->id = value;
  auxNode->next = NULL;

  current->next = auxNode;

}
```

Again, by printing, I have determined that both of them crash when checking the next node of the linked list. That is, in

> for(i; current->next != NULL; i++)

and

> while((current->next) != NULL)

I'm sorry for the extension of my question, and would greatly appreciate any help on this matter. So thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is the entire code in case is needed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Lists.c"


typedef struct Nodo
{
    int id;         // Representative value
    int checked;        // 0 if the node wasn't visited; and 1 if it was.
} Node;

void initializeLocker(int n, Node nodeLocker[n])
{
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        nodeLocker[i].id = i;
        nodeLocker[i].checked = 0;
    }
}

void matrixBfs(int n, int matrix[n][n], Node nodeLocker[n], int source)
{
    int aux;
    Box* head =(Box*) malloc(sizeof(Box*));
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory failure\n");
    }
    head->next = NULL;

    add(head, source);
    nodeLocker[source].checked = 1;

    while (len(head) > 0)
    {
        aux = pop(head);

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if ((matrix[aux][i]) && !(nodeLocker[i].checked))
            {
                add(head, i);
                nodeLocker[i].checked = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    head = NULL;
    free(head);
}

int main()
{
  FILE* file = fopen("Input.in","r");
  char c[5];
  char* pch;
  int n;
  int num;
  int num2;

  fgets(c, 5, file);

  n = atoi(c);  // Number of nodes.

  if (n < 0)
  {
    printf("Must input at least one node");
    exit(1);
  }

  int matrix[n][n];

  // Initialization loop
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }


  // Insertion loop.
  while(fgets(c, 5, file))
  {
    pch = strtok(c, " ");
    num = atoi(pch) - 1;
    pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
    num2 = atoi(pch) - 1;
    matrix[num][num2] = 1;
    matrix[num2][num] = 1;
  }

  fclose(file);             // No further use of the file.
  pch = NULL;
  free(pch);

  Node nodeLocker[n];

  initializeLocker(n, nodeLocker);

  matrixBfs(n, matrix, nodeLocker, 0);

  for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    if(nodeLocker[i].checked == 0)
    {
        printf("The entered graph has at least 1 node aislated. Please enter 
a new graph.");
        exit(1);
    }
  }

  initializeLocker(n, nodeLocker);
  nodeLocker[0].checked = 1;
  matrixBfs(n, matrix, nodeLocker, 1);

  for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
  {
    if (nodeLocker[i].checked == 0)
    {
        printf("%d is a linker agent.\n", 1);
        break;
    }
  }

  for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
  {
    initializeLocker(n, nodeLocker);
    nodeLocker[i].checked = 1;
    matrixBfs(n, matrix, nodeLocker, 0);

    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        if (nodeLocker[j].checked == 0)
        {
            printf("%d is a linker agent.\n", i+1);
            break;
        }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The "Box" structure is defined in this file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Box
{
  int id;
  struct Box* next;
} Box;

// Adds an element at the end of the list.
void add(Box* head, int value)
{
  Box* current = head;
  Box* next = NULL;

  if (current != NULL)
  {
     next = current->next;
  }

  while(next != NULL)
  {
    current = next;
    next = current->next;
  }

  Box* auxNode = (Box*) malloc(sizeof(Box*));

  if (auxNode == NULL)
  {
    printf("Memory failure\n");
  }
  auxNode->id = value;
  auxNode->next = NULL;

  current->next = auxNode;

}

// Returns the length of the list
int len(Box* head)
{
 int i = 0;
 Box* current = head;
 Box* next = NULL;

 if (current != NULL)
 {
     next = current->next;
 }

 for(i; next != NULL; i++)
 {
    current = next;
    next = current-> next;
  }
  return i;
}

// Prints the entire list
void printLine(Box* head)
{
  if (head->next == NULL)
  {
    printf("The list is empty\n");
    return;
  }

  Box* current = head;

  current = current->next;
  printf("[%d", (current->id) + 1);

  while (current->next != NULL)
  {
    current = current->next;
    printf(", %d", (current->id) + 1);
  }

  printf("]\n");
}

// Deletes and returns the last element of the list
int pop(Box* head)
{
  Box* auxNode;
  int value;

  if (len(head) == 1)
  {
    auxNode = head->next;
    head->next = NULL;
    value = auxNode->id;
    auxNode = NULL;
    free(auxNode);
    return value;
  }

  Box* current = head;

  while (current->next->next != NULL)
  {
    current = current->next;
  }

  auxNode = current->next;
  value = current->next->id;
  current->next = NULL;
  auxNode = NULL;
  free(auxNode);
  return value;
}
```

Finally, the input is entered using the "Input.txt" file. Here, the first line shows the number of nodes of the graph, and the rest shows the connections between them:

```
9
1 2
1 3
1 5
2 3
2 5
3 5
4 7
5 6
5 7
5 9
6 7
6 9
7 8
7 9
8 9
```

Comment: For large inputs, use the array allocated with `malloc` instead of VLA.

Comment: `Box* head =(Box*) malloc(sizeof(Box*));` should be `Box* head = (Box*) malloc(sizeof(Box));` and so on.  (Required size is insufficient. :-)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks! that solved the problem! If you could, could you explain me in more detail what was wrong?

Comment: The pointer points to the object(`Box`) is not a pointer(`Box*`). (Try `printf("%zu, %zu", sizeof(Box), sizeof(Box*);`) And Since the VLA is reserved on the stack, its size is limited by the stack size.

Comment: The size to be secured is not a pointer size(`sizeof(Box*)`), but `sizeof(int)`(as `id`)  + `sizeof(Box*)`(as `next`) (and padding if there is any) are necessary.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thank you, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

In both the statements causing segmentation fault, you are not checking if current is NULL. Instead use something like this in both len and add functions:

```
int len(Box* head)
{
  int i = 0;
  Box* current = head;
  Box* next = NULL;

  if (current != NULL) {
      next = current->next;
  }

  for(i; next != NULL; i++)
  {
    current = next;
    next = current-> next;
  }
  return i;
}


// Adds an element at the end of the list
void add(Box* head, int value)
{
  Box* current = head;
  Box* next = NULL;

  if (current != NULL) {
      next = current->next;
  }

  while(next != NULL)
  {
    current = next;
    next = current->next;
  }

  Box* auxNode = (Box*) malloc(sizeof(Box*));

  if (auxNode == NULL)
  {
    printf("Memory failure\n");
  }
  auxNode->id = value;
  auxNode->next = NULL;

  current->next = auxNode;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but it keeps crashing.

Comment: @Alkeindem: Can you use gdb and find out exact line where it is crashing. I suspect now it be must be crashing somewhere else. Refer this in case you are not familiar with gdb: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876357/determine-the-line-of-c-code-that-causes-a-segmentation-fault

Comment: Here is something strange. I ran it using gdb and it did not crash, and the output where the expected ones. But I ran it again without gdb and crashed.

Comment: What is the gdb output?

Comment: [Thread 11336. 0x3668 exited with code 0]
[Inferior 1  (process 11336) exited normally]

Comment: Are you passing the same input to gdb and normal execution? Please post the entire code and the inputs you are specifying to the code.

Comment: Sure. I'll do it. The inputs are in a .txt file, so they are constant.

Comment: Okay, added the entire code. Still, you can ignore all the input work, that ends at "free(pch)"