# Determine place of segmentation error CMake

Tags: c++, debugging, cmake

I am trying to figure out where a segmentation error is made. Thesame issue has been solved below for a different compiler. I am using CMake and am wondering if this compiler also has this function. CMake has no `-g` build option so I have no idea where to look.

[Determine the line of code that causes a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876357/determine-the-line-of-code-that-causes-a-segmentation-fault?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[image: CMake Debugger info]

Here is also some info on what build options there are available for the debugger, maybe this points out what debugger I use since I have no idea.

```
/usr/bin/make: invalid option -- 'g'
Usage: make [options] [target] ...
Options:
  -b, -m                      Ignored for compatibility.
  -B, --always-make           Unconditionally make all targets.
  -C DIRECTORY, --directory=DIRECTORY
                              Change to DIRECTORY before doing anything.
  -d                          Print lots of debugging information.
  --debug[=FLAGS]             Print various types of debugging information.
  -e, --environment-overrides
                              Environment variables override makefiles.
  --eval=STRING               Evaluate STRING as a makefile statement.
  -f FILE, --file=FILE, --makefile=FILE
                              Read FILE as a makefile.
  -h, --help                  Print this message and exit.
  -i, --ignore-errors         Ignore errors from recipes.
  -I DIRECTORY, --include-dir=DIRECTORY
                              Search DIRECTORY for included makefiles.
  -j [N], --jobs[=N]          Allow N jobs at once; infinite jobs with no arg.
  -k, --keep-going            Keep going when some targets can't be made.
  -l [N], --load-average[=N], --max-load[=N]
                              Don't start multiple jobs unless load is below N.
  -L, --check-symlink-times   Use the latest mtime between symlinks and target.
  -n, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon
                              Don't actually run any recipe; just print them.
  -o FILE, --old-file=FILE, --assume-old=FILE
                              Consider FILE to be very old and don't remake it.
  -O[TYPE], --output-sync[=TYPE]
                              Synchronize output of parallel jobs by TYPE.
  -p, --print-data-base       Print make's internal database.
  -q, --question              Run no recipe; exit status says if up to date.
  -r, --no-builtin-rules      Disable the built-in implicit rules.
  -R, --no-builtin-variables  Disable the built-in variable settings.
  -s, --silent, --quiet       Don't echo recipes.
  -S, --no-keep-going, --stop
                              Turns off -k.
  -t, --touch                 Touch targets instead of remaking them.
  --trace                     Print tracing information.
  -v, --version               Print the version number of make and exit.
  -w, --print-directory       Print the current directory.
  --no-print-directory        Turn off -w, even if it was turned on implicitly.
  -W FILE, --what-if=FILE, --new-file=FILE, --assume-new=FILE
                              Consider FILE to be infinitely new.
  --warn-undefined-variables  Warn when an undefined variable is referenced.

This program built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Report bugs to <bug-make@gnu.org>
```

Comment: CMake is not a compiler. Find which compiler you are using and use a compatible debugger.

Comment: What compiler are you using for CMAKE?

Comment: Could you show your `CMakeLists.txt` you seem to have added `-g` to the wrong setting in CMake.

Comment: Note that using a build type of `Debug` or `RelWithDebInfo` will add the `-g` compiler flag automatically; you don't need to add it yourself (which appears to be the reason you are seeing this error)

Comment: Those are the options for CMAKE, not the compiler or debugger.  CMAKE is a build system.  You make a file describing how your code should be compiled and then CMAKE uses that to have the compiler compile the code.