# Segmentation fault when passing big integers as values in vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

Getting segmentation fault(Core Dumped) when big integers are passed. It works fine for smaller inputs.

Replaced `int` with `long int` and also tried to declare the variables globally, but still the same error. This function is used to perform a number of right circular rotations and return the value of the element at a given index. Here is the function:

```
    vector<long long int> circularArrayRotation(vector<long long int> a, long long int k, vector<long long int> queries) {
        vector <long long int> b;
        std::vector<long long int> result(queries.size());

        b=a;
        for(long long int j=0;j<k;j++)
        {
            for(long long int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
                a[i]=b[(a.size()+i-1)%a.size()];
            b=a;
        }

        for(long long int k=0;k<queries.size();k++)
            result[k]=a[queries[k]];
        for(long long int i=0;i<result.size();i++)
                cout<<result[i]<<endl;

        return result;

    }
```

The remaining code can be found here [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/circular-array-rotation/problem)

Comment: Please show a [mre], what are the parameters to your function? What is your function supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quality of the implementation aside (there is no need to make any copy to rotate a vector, it can be done in-place), most probably the error causing the segfault is in the code that's not shown.

To debug this further the following links might be of use:

- [How to debug with gdb?](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html)
- [Determine the line of code that causes a segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876357/determine-the-line-of-code-that-causes-a-segmentation-fault)

If you need further assistance, post your entire code.

**== EDIT ==**

Your code isn't triggering a segfault but a "Terminated due to timeout" error on HackerRank. In other words, your solution is too slow.

That's because there is no need to rotate anything to solve [Circular Array Rotation](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/circular-array-rotation/problem):

```
vector<int> circularArrayRotation(vector<int> a, int k, vector<int> queries) {
    vector<int> res;
    res.reserve(queries.size());
    int offset = k % a.size() - a.size();
    for (int i : queries) {
        res.push_back(a[(i - offset) % a.size()]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

i.e. just take the rotation into account when selecting the requested element.

Comment: Only this function was written by me and all the other was prewritten.It can be found here [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/circular-array-rotation/problem)

Comment: You should have posted that link in the question. See my updated answer.

Comment: It showed segmentation fault error on my machine. Anyways thanks for pointing the mistake

Answer (score 0):

A `vector` is backed by an array of continuous memory, and your machine isn't able to allocate such a large array.

You could consider using a [`list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) instead, but would probably need to rewrite the code to use iterators if you care about performance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be queries[k] > a.size() at line 
`result[k]=a[queries[k]];`
As we don't know actual inputs, it is really hard to pinpoint the reason.