# Unable to identify reasons for signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, ubuntu, segmentation-fault

I am running a cpp program in ubuntu. I am getting a signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

I tried to use gdb to see the exact line for segmentation fault. I get this idea from this thread of question:

[Determine the line of code that causes a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876357/determine-the-line-of-code-that-causes-a-segmentation-fault)

The gdb is returning me this:

```
Thread 1 "incremental_sat" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7857c50 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(char const*) const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

Please see the screenshot of the terminal below:

[image]

I am using data structure involving all types of vector and unordered_map for int and string.

Can I know, which all lines of code is responsible for this error?

I am new to debugging in CPP. Any suggestion for the direction I can proceed with this info?

UPDATE: after the suggestion of running "bt" command, I am adding the output:

[image]

I am observing that it is getting segmentation fault just after calling cnf_transformation_out_diff() function. As it is not even printing the first cout command written in cnf_transformation_out_diff() function.

[image]

Comment: Type `bt` in `gdb`.

Comment: updated by question following your suggestion. Please look into it. @MaximEgorushkin

Comment: Please don't show _pictures_ of text. Show text instead.

Comment: Your program is compiled without debug info. Rebuild it with `-g` flag, and the output from `bt` will be much more useful.

Comment: @EmployedRussian This issue is resolved. I noted down the suggestion for the next time. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I resolved the bug with the help of my friend Arpan.

In one scenario, the data structure gates_out_diff remained empty. I didn't added the safety check and the program is accessing the gates_out_diff[i][1] value, so it resulted in a segmentation fault.

It is running after I fixed that case. It took me one day. Hope it saves someone's time.