# Enabling cookies in libwget causes Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, http, https, debian, wget

I am trying to learn using libwget on Debian 12. I've installed the package "wget2-dev" which recursively installed "libwget0" package. I wrote a very basic and simple application with the help of [wget2 examples](https://gitlab.com/gnuwget/wget2/-/blob/master/examples/http_get.c).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wget.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wget_http_connection_t *conn = NULL;
    wget_http_response_t *resp;

    // set up libwget global configuration
    wget_global_init(
        WGET_COOKIES_ENABLED, 1,
        WGET_COOKIE_SUFFIXES, "public_suffixes.txt",
        WGET_COOKIE_FILE, "cookies.txt",
        WGET_COOKIE_KEEPSESSIONCOOKIES, 1,
        0);

    // execute an HTTP GET request and return the response
    resp = wget_http_get(
        WGET_HTTP_URL, "http://example.com",
        WGET_HTTP_MAX_REDIRECTIONS, 5,
        WGET_HTTP_CONNECTION_PTR, &conn,
        0);

    if (resp)
    {
        printf("%s", resp->body->data);

        // free the response
        wget_http_free_response(&resp);
    }
    // close connection if still open
    wget_http_close(&conn);
    // free resources - needed for valgrind testing
    wget_global_deinit();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My problem is that, while calling wget_global_init function, if I set "WGET_COOKIES_ENABLED" to "1", I get a Segmentation Fault.

What is the problem here? Is that because of the library or am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

EDIT: I tried the answer in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876357/determine-the-line-of-code-that-causes-a-segmentation-fault?rq=2) related to Segmentation Fault. If I type

```
gdb ./MyApp
```

I get

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: MyApp 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x0) at ./nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:80
80  ./nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c: No such file or directory.
```

What does that mean? How can I solve it?

EDIT 2: If I type

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./MyApp
```

I get

```
==42170== Invalid read of size 4
==42170==    at 0x49541C0: pthread_mutex_lock@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_mutex_lock.c:80)
==42170==    by 0x487A7EC: wget_cookie_create_request_header (in /usr/lib/libwget.so.0.0.0)
==42170==    by 0x4895153: wget_http_get (in /usr/lib/libwget.so.0.0.0)
==42170==    by 0x1091EE: main (main.c:23)
==42170==  Address 0x10 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==42170== 
==42170== 
==42170== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==42170==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x10
==42170==    at 0x49541C0: pthread_mutex_lock@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_mutex_lock.c:80)
==42170==    by 0x487A7EC: wget_cookie_create_request_header (in /usr/lib/libwget.so.0.0.0)
==42170==    by 0x4895153: wget_http_get (in /usr/lib/libwget.so.0.0.0)
==42170==    by 0x1091EE: main (main.c:23)
```

Is that a bug, or am I not using the library correctly?

EDIT 3: After the comment by [Olaf Dietsche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1741542/olaf-dietsche), I added `-lpthread` to Build Settings in Eclipse CDT

```
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -lpthread -I/usr/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.o" -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.c"
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc -lpthread -L/usr/lib -o "MyApp" ./src/main.o    -lwget
```

I am still getting the same error when I run the program.

EDIT 4: I added `-lpthread` to GCC Linker options too after another comment by [Olaf Dietsche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1741542/olaf-dietsche). And I am still getting Segmentation Fault.

Comment: How did you compile and link the program? Have you used the `-pthread` option?

Comment: The stack in the first example already shows, that the program segfaults because of a null pointer access. So it looks like the mutex or some mutex pointer isn't initialized properly.

Comment: If pthreads are relevant here (I don't know), you must add this option to both the compiler and linker.

Comment: I think I should ask it in Github since it seems it is related to library internals. Thanks Olaf.

Comment: Please revise code so it's the segfault version not the one that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's a bug in the library (d51398947e150e930299f3c9657aaf6204489f4d) where `wget_global_get_ptr()` returns a `&_config.cookie_db` but caller `wget_http_get()` expects a `_config.cookie_db`.  This fix shipped in v2.0.0 and the current version in Debian is 1.99.1-2.2.

   @rockdaboot mentioned it's fixed in Debian testing so you could [install that package from testing](https://serverfault.com/questions/22414/how-can-i-run-debian-stable-but-install-some-packages-from-testing).
2. Once you get a fixed version of the library you probably want to specify `WGET_COOKIE_FILE` which sets `WGET_COOKIES_ENABLED`.

Please file report a bug to Debian against the package libwget0.

Bonus: It turns out that the wget (binary) doesn't depend on libwget0.

Comment: Just want to confirm that `libwget` has been introduced with `wget2`. The "good old" `wget` does not depend on `libwget`.

Comment: Firstly, thank you both for your answers. Secondly, Allan, after using WGET_COOKIE_FILE, it still gives a segmentation fault. I've updated the code.

Comment: By the way, I am sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @ukll Sorry for being unclear.  You will hit this bug even with  WGET_COOKIE_FILE is set so it was more about setting it once you get a fixed library.

Comment: How unfortunate. :) Thanks though.

Comment: @ukll I added a link to installing a package from testing.  It takes a few minutes to do.

Comment: @AllanWind I've found a better way. From https://debian.pkgs.org/sid/debian-main-amd64/, I've downloaded and installed the packages wget2_2.1.0-2+b1_amd64.deb, wget2-dev_2.1.0-2+b1_amd64.deb, libwget2_2.1.0-2+b1_amd64.deb, liblz1_1.13-6_amd64.deb. No configuration needed. :)

Comment: Other dependencies were already installed.

Answer (score 1):

Allan Wind pointed it out: that bug has been fixed in September 2019, but only got into Debian testing (trixie) so far.

FYA, `wget_http_connection_t` was renamed to `wget_http_connection`
and `wget_http_response_t` was renamed to `wget_http_response`.

I'd suggest to build and install libwget (and wget2) from tarball. Instructions can be found at [here](https://gitlab.com/gnuwget/wget2#downloading-and-building-from-tarball).

Alternatively, upgrade your system to Debian testing to stay with relatively modern software versions without the downside of running a "bleeding edge" system.

Comment: It's not supported and it makes upgrades a little less pleasant but op can also install the version from testing https://serverfault.com/questions/22414/how-can-i-run-debian-stable-but-install-some-packages-from-testing