# Where can I find the report that crashpad generate?

Tags: c++, c, crash, crashpad

I compile the demo of crashpad(`https://github.com/backtrace-labs/crashpad`) in /crashpad/examples/linux/demo.
And set the url is
`std::string url("https://submit.backtrace.io/yolo/20231222_test_demo/minidump");`
handler_path is:
`/home/crashpad/handler/handler`

when I run the ./demo_linux, I don't know where to find the report.
demo output:

```
./demo_linux
Crashpad URL: https://submit.backtrace.io/yolo/20231222_test_demo/minidump
Crashpad handler: /home/crashpad/handler/handler
Crashpad database: .
45
50
[33723:33723:20231222,085316.039468:ERROR socket.cc:93] sendmsg: Broken pipe (32)
0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Did you create a backtrace.io account and (somehow) associate it with that URL? Honestly the presence of a broken pipe error is not reassuring.

Comment: What report you are looking for? Are you interested in backtrace for ``Segmentation fault```? For that use ```GDB``` and look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2876374/5821185) for more info.