# android.media.MediaPlayer crashes without exception

Tags: android, exception, media-player

The [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) makes my app freeze without throwing an exception when I pass corrupted audio files to it. Here's my code:

```
try
{
    if (this.mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
    {
        this.mediaPlayer.reset();
    }

    this.mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this.currentSong.getFile() /* path string */);
    this.mediaPlayer.prepare();
    this.mediaPlayer.start();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.v("Oh snap", "MediaPlayer exception: " + e.toString());
}
```

What can I do about this? I need an exception to handle corrupted files properly. The test device is a Samsung Galaxy S2 running Android 2.3.6 and I'm targeting API level 8.

I'm not sure what's wrong with the corrupted flac files that I'm passing to the MediaPlayer. All I know is that they crash my app and the stock music player too, which shouldn't happen.

Comment: Yes, no exceptions or warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a native crash there's very little you can do just from the Java layer. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083154/how-can-i-catch-sigsegv-segmentation-fault-and-get-a-stack-trace-under-jni-on) for a slightly scary guide to the frightful hacking you'd need to do.