# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) while running project

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a weird error and I can't find where it comes from. The only thing that appears in the logcat is :[image]

01-10 17:07:10.665: A/libc(20449): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)

Comment: There is no way to tell whats going out without a stack trace.  Apparently this is difficult to do on Jelly Bean, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083154/how-can-i-catch-sigsegv-segmentation-fault-and-get-a-stack-trace-under-jni-on  If I was to guess, a null pointer is being used somewhere.

Comment: One more thing, is that suppose to be 0x0000000c or 0x00000000?  If it is 0x0000000c, like it is in the screenshot, then I think you may have done something like int * i; i = 12; instead of *i = 12;

Comment: An offset of 0x0c (12) usually means that you tried to dereference a pointer to a struct but the pointer was NULL.  If the struct has a bunch of 32-bit ints or pointers, an offset of 12 would indicate that the 4th element was accessed.  Normally you'd get a debuggerd dump and stack trace, but there are various things an app can do that will confuse that.