# gdb catchpoint for uncaught C++ exceptions only?

Tags: c++, exception, gdb, breakpoints

I can tell the gdb debugger to stop as soon as any C++ exception is thrown by setting a catchpoint with the gdb command

```
catch throw
```

However, is there any way to only stop at **uncaught** C++ exceptions (like in C# or Java)? This would make it much easier to find bugs in some situations.

Thanks!

Comment: related - [How do I find where an exception was thrown in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2443135/203667)

Comment: I don't think I understand - how do you determine if an exception is uncaught other than by letting it unroll until it breaks through the toplevel?

Comment: Well, I guess gdb would have to check whether the exception is caught or not *before* actually unwinding the stack. I don't know how C# or Java solve this, but I'm just curious if it can be done in C++ anyhow.

Comment: @Mat: depends on the C++ implementation, but it's perfectly feasible that the exception-handling code can look up the stack twice: once to find out whether there's a catch point, and then again to unwind the stack. Note that it is implementation-defined whether an uncaught exception results in destructors being called all the way up the stack, or an immediate call to `terminate` without stack unwinding.

Comment: The manual way (if exceptions are exceptional) is to `catch throw` and `catch catch`. That will stop whenever an exception is thrown (annotate where) and then when it is caught, if after `continue` the program calls terminate with an uncaught exception (i.e. does not stop in the `catch catch` you know where the last throw occurred)

Comment: @Steve Jessop: thanks for the information, that makes sens.

Comment: The GNU C++ exception implementation actually _does_ walk the whole stack to see if there is a handler before it pops any frames. There are some languages where the handler must run _on top_ of the frame that threw the exception (Common Lisp?), and the folks designing the "new" GNU C++ exception handling system wanted both C++-like and CL-like languages to be able to share stacks and exception machinery. So the information is there. (Unfortunately, I don't know the answer to the actual question --- whether GDB can catch these.)

Comment: (I never used GDB's features in this area because they were always broken. And I was a GDB developer. :( )

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If an exception is uncaught, the special library function **[`terminate()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/exception/terminate/)** is automatically called.  Terminate is actually a pointer to a function and default value is the Standard C library function [`abort()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/abort/).  You *may* be able to set a breakpoint on the call to the [`abort()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/abort/) function and identify the location of the uncaught exception from there.

```
break abort
...
run
...
bt
```

---

You can install your own **[`terminate()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/exception/terminate/)** function by using **[`std::set_terminate()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/exception/set_terminate/)**.  You should be able to set a breakpoint on your terminate function in gdb.  You *may* be able to generate a stack backtrace from your **[`terminate()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/exception/terminate/)** function and this backtrace *may* help in identifying the location of the exception.  Additional details are provided [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443135/how-do-i-find-where-an-exception-was-thrown-in-c/2445569#2445569).

Comment: Thanks, it works for me with set_terminate() - using g++ 4.5.0, gdb 7.2