# PhantomJs.exe throwing "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' " error on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: jasmine, phantomjs

I trying to run my jamsine specs from command line using PhantomJs.exe. Here is my command line

```
'path\to\phantomjs\phantomjs.exe run-jasmine.js SpecRunner.html
```

I'm running this from the folder where my spec runner html file is located. The above command throws following error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what(): std::bad_alloc

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I have already looked at http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=365 on phantomjs group but that does not help much for someone like me who comes from a .net background.

So far I have found out that version 1.3.0 of PhantomJs works fine for me.

Comment: Not a PhantomJS exert, but std::bad_alloc is a most often caused by running out of memory.

Comment: I agree. But I'm seeing this with only phantomjs.exe and that too everytime  use Phantomjs.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this url on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177152/what-is-the-cause-of-this-application-has-requested-the-runtime-to-terminate-it).

This is a typicall situation that takes place when a conflict of instances of C Runtime (CRT) libraries is detected! One app ist bound statically to the CRT and at the same time the app tries to dynamically bind to CRT.

Comment: I get that now. But how should I fix the problem?

Comment: ...contact the one that built the bits, the application offensing the system! :-(

Comment: ...and tag this question as answered? :-)

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question but saved me time by pointing to the fact that the library itself may be problematic. I started using an older version which works for me now (original question updated to reflect this)