# handling dll issue popup window

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll

Am trying to use the project found [here](https://github.com/Robotips/uConfig), I have made some modifications and the code works okey, but sometimes it throws the below error.
How can I suppress or handle that error message in code, as it stops logic flow from continuing untill the button is pressed manually

[image: error message]

after debgugging abit, I can find the error is thrown in a `delete` line, it tries to delete a pointer and it prints `std::bad_alloc` then hangs

Comment: why do you think, it's related to a missing dll?

Comment: @JörgBeyer, sorry, I have edited the question title

Comment: [*What is the cause of “This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way”?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177152/what-is-the-cause-of-this-application-has-requested-the-runtime-to-terminate-it) - [`abort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/k089yyh0(v=vs.140))

Comment: I think this a crash or assertion, try running it in a debugger.

Comment: i searched the project but `abort()` is not called explicitly, it could be called in one of the DLLs am using, is a `try catch` will solve it ?

Comment: To call `abort()` directly is unusual (although possible). Writing `assert()`s into your code, you involve potential calls to `abort()` (because this what actually is called when asserted condition doesn't hold). `try`/`catch` wouldn't help (probably) because `abort()` is often called for things which cannot be catched (like e.g. memory access errors).

Comment: what options do I have to suprress this then ?

Comment: To suppress to call of `abort()` you have to eliminate the bugs from the code of DLL which cause its call. `abort()` is usually called when fatal errors occurred (e.g. an Access Violation) or things which shouldn't happen in correct code (like in `assert()`s).