# Running an executable from Python "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way."

Tags: python, powershell, visual-c++, cmd, python-os

I'm getting an interesting problem and I can't determine whether it's a problem with my code or the executable that I'm running. Basically I have a Python program that needs to call an external executable to process some data. If I call the executable via PowerShell or cmd, it works fine. However, if I attempt to run the executable via `os.system()` or `subprocess.run()`, I get the following error:

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>   Please contact the application's support team for more information.

From my understanding of googling the issue, it would appear that this is some sort of C++-related issue, which is the language of the .exe that I'm running. I reinstalled the latest Visual C++ Redist and that did not seem to affect the problem. I've also tried to create a .bat and .ps1 script that runs the .exe. These both run fine via PowerShell and CMD, but raise the same error when run via `os.system()` and `subprocess.run()`. The error message is rather nondescript so I'm wondering if anyone knows anything about it and why `os.system()` etc. might be throwing it.

The relevant code is simply

```python
os.system("GaussBin.exe gaussInput.txt gaussOutput.txt")
```

When the string is pasted into cmd, it runs perfectly. Additionally, if the parameters of the `system()` call are incorrect, the exe properly displays the usage function. It's only when I add the output.txt and the program is supposed to run fully that things start to break.

I've had some confusion about what directory `os.system` runs in. Should I be using `.\` when calling the exe?

The .exe file is provided, not built by me.

Comment: Is the `.exe` a program you wrote an built yourself? You should also edit your question to at least include the code where you run the program with `os.system`.

Comment: The exe is failing in controlled a manner for [some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8177152/503046).

Comment: You should be seeing a different error message if Python were unable to find the executable.

Comment: Does this mean that it's a problem with the cpp executable itself? I don't understand how it's failing when called via python but not when called via a batch file/powershell script/directly through command line

Comment: GaussBin.exe still runs fine via the cmd loaded from that directory. Comspec is the system32 cmd but that also runs the command fine on its own. 

I expect the directory running GaussBin via the program to just be the directory the program is run from, and assumed that's how it would work.

Comment: I'm getting an exit code of 3 from the program, according to the %errorlevel% echo. Looking at the source code of gaussBin, there's nowhere specifically that would return 3, so I'm not quite sure how this is happening.

Comment: @PWallington The error message means that the `abort()` function is called, which ends the program with an exit code of 3.

Comment: I read that, but I still fail to see how a program could be acting differently when called programatically as opposed to being called manually as long as the inputs are the exact same @MrPromethee