# Ruby/Watir - segfault on browser.close

Tags: ruby, linux, segmentation-fault, watir

My PC has been randomly locking up lately, and while debugging I found an issue with my Ruby/Watir project. Each time the browser.close function is called, the following occurs in dmesg (slightly different each time):

`[12614.684243] Chrome_~dThread[29941]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f17889b3992 sp 00007f1786aa0b00 error 6 in libxul.so[7f1787b6a000+519c000]`

I'm not sure if this is causing my PC to lock up, however it still needs resolving. I've done some searching but I can't find anyone else with this issue. The issue also appears if I `ctrl + c` the script.

Error 6 is: `The cause was a user-mode write resulting in no page being found.`, which makes sense if I've closed the browser.

I've read the answer on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549214/interpreting-segfault-messages), but as libxul.so is a library it didn't help much (although offered me a better understanding of debugging segfaults!).

For those looking due to the linux/segfault tag rather than ruby/watir, browser.close is a builtin function in the Watir package.

Edit:

- Although it says 'Chrome', the issue actually comes from FireFox
- I don't get the issue in any other browser
- libxul.so is found in `/usr/lib/firefox/`

Comment: Are you only having the problem using browsers other than Chrome? When the process ends (either `ctrl + c` or `browser.close`) Watir will kill the `chromedriver` process. I have no experience with libxul, but perhaps the issue is the system trying to do that. Also, I'm pretty sure "page" in this context has nothing to do with the a browser "page." :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that this error comes from FireFox (not sure why it says Chrome...). I don't get the error on other browsers. Added more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually the result of a PC hardware issue that wasn't apparent till much later.