# several segmentation fault for different processes

Tags: ubuntu, segmentation-fault

I have installed ubuntu 18 recently and having problems of several segmentation faults from running different programs such as python, nano.

The syslog looks like this:

```
Feb  4 18:50:04 dmcb-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 5368.279040] nano[12154]: segfault at 56956c2ce1e0 ip 000056056aa019d9 sp 00007ffd0396c478 error 4 in nano[56056a9f2000+3b000]
Feb  4 19:37:52 dmcb-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 8236.744267] sshd[12526]: segfault at 7fa9094e29d8 ip 00007fed092ec749 sp 00007ffde26ffaf0 error 4 in ld-2.27.so[7fed092db000+27000]
Feb  4 19:37:52 dmcb-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 8237.023587] apport[12529]: segfault at 80009d45e9 ip 000000000059cc34 sp 00007ffd65dbeda8 error 4 in python3.6[400000+3b4000]
```

I am currently debugging this error but is not sure what the problem is.
Since segmentation fault comes from different processes randomly, I am supposing hardware is the cause.
Some insights would really help. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure this is even a valid programming question for Stack Overflow. Maybe askubuntu.com or superuser.com would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Segfaults can be caused by a variety of errors, ad you may find [Interpreting segfault messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549214/interpreting-segfault-messages) helpful in understanding some of the possibilities.

One possible reason, other than a software bug, is corruption caused by faulty memory. The first thing to try is reseating all memory modules, and turn down any overclocking.

Beyond that, there is little you can do without VERY specialised equipment to diagnose hardware faults, especially if they are intermittent.