# what's the meaning of error number in /var/log/messages?

Tags: linux

the context in /var/log/messages is:

```
ep 24 16:51:35 12006745D kernel: gdns_processor[5978]: segfault at ffffffffffffffe9 rip 0000003a3349d302 rsp 00000000536044e0 error 4
Sep 24 18:38:34 12006745D kernel: gdns_processor[20452]: segfault at ffffffffffffffe8 rip 0000003a3349d302 rsp 0000000052e834e0 error 4
Sep 25 14:58:01 12006745D auditd[3955]: Audit daemon rotating log files
Sep 25 15:18:50 12006745D yum: Installed: 2:vim-common-7.0.109-7.el5.x86_64
Sep 25 15:18:51 12006745D yum: Installed: 2:vim-enhanced-7.0.109-7.el5.x86_64
Sep 25 15:18:52 12006745D yum: Installed: 2:vim-X11-7.0.109-7.el5.x86_64
Sep 25 15:25:10 12006745D kernel: a.out[1694]: segfault at 0000000000000000 rip 0000000000400458 rsp 00007fffe69073a0 error 6
Sep 25 15:29:33 12006745D kernel: a.out[8132]: segfault at 0000000000000000 rip 0000000000400458 rsp 00007fffa01fbb50 error 6
Sep 25 17:57:29 12006745D kernel: gdns_processor[11504]: segfault at 0000000000594598 rip 0000003a3349d338 rsp 0000000052caf4e0 error 7
Sep 25 18:08:05 12006745D kernel: t1[28050]: segfault at 0000000000000000 rip 0000000000400458 rsp 00007fff5ecb0850 error 6
```

What's the meaning of **4** in "`Sep 24 18:38:34 12006745D kernel: gdns_processor[20452]: segfault at ffffffffffffffe8 rip 0000003a3349d302 rsp 0000000052e834e0 error 4"`?

also the same question about **6** and **7**.

Thank you

Comment: why does it have C++ tag?

Comment: @zoska gdns_processor built by C++  and t1 built by C

Comment: If you wish this to be a c/c++ question, you should provide some code. As it is, the question is about linux log errors only

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you read a segfault kernel log message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179403/how-do-you-read-a-segfault-kernel-log-message)

Comment: I don't know what the error number means but `segfault at ffffffffffffffe8` brings the nature of the error into focus on two fronts. First, a segfault is an attempt to access memory you don't have permission to access (perhaps because it doesn't exist). Second, the address is what you get if you start with NULL and subtract from it the size of a single pointer on a 64 bit machine (which suggests how this particular segfault occurred).

Comment: @Leeor I will update it. thank you

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @zakinster This post is 3 years old, it's possible, that during that time something changed in kernel. I wouldn't be so strict about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `/arch/<architecture>/mm/fault.c` :

```
Page fault error code bits:

bit 0 ==    0: no page found   1: protection fault
bit 1 ==    0: read access     1: write access
bit 2 ==    0: kernel-mode access  1: user-mode access
bit 3 ==               1: use of reserved bit detected
bit 4 ==               1: fault was an instruction fetch
```