# Segmentation Fault during pthread_join()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads, pthread-join

I've got a program which has 10 Guest threads, 1 check-in thread, and 1 check-out thread.  All threads are created using `pthread_create()` within my `Main()` method.

The whole thing runs well until the end where the `Main()` method is supposed to `pthread_join()` with the line `pthread_join(desk[1], NULL);` at which time a `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)` error is thrown.

I know it gets to that point because of the output I see in the console.

I use `gcc -pthread FileName.c` and `./a.out` to compile and execute.

Can you see why I get an error at that point in my code?

The entire program is posted below:

```
//Hotel Project 
//This project creates a system to simulate a hotel.

#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define NUM_GUESTS  5 //10 guests

/*GLOBAL VARIABLE*/ int globalVar0; // Check-in guestID
/*GLOBAL VARIABLE*/ int globalVar1; // Check-out guestID
/*GLOBAL VARIABLE*/ int globalVar2; // Check-out room

void *CheckIn(void *); // the two threads
void *CheckOut(void *);

pthread_t guests[NUM_GUESTS];
pthread_t desk[2];

sem_t roomSem;              //total number of rooms in the hotel
sem_t check_in, check_out;  //reception desks
sem_t s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6;   //global semaphores
sem_t roomArraySem;
sem_t randSem;

int rooms[5] = {1,1,1,1,1}; //keep track of availability of each room

int total_guests;       //incremented with each guest check-out
int pool;               //incremented with each guest use pool
int resturant;          //incremented with each guest use resturant
int fitness_center;     //incremented with each guest use fitness center
int business_center;    //incremented with each guest use business center

struct thread_data
{
    int guest_id;   // id number of guest
    int room;       // room guest utilizes
    int event;      // 0=swim, 1=resturaunt, 2=fitness, 3=business
    int cost;       // final cost of stay (random value)
};

struct thread_data thread_data_array[NUM_GUESTS]; // array initialization

void *Guest(void *guestData)
{
    int guestid, guestroom, gevent, gcost, sleepVal;
    struct thread_data *guest_data;

    guest_data = (struct thread_data *) guestData;

    guestid = guest_data->guest_id; // guest_id stored in struct

    sem_wait(&roomSem);

    /*output*/ printf("Guest %d waits for check-in\n", guestid);
    sem_wait(&check_in); // if there is a room available, guest approaches check_in clerk; making him busy
        /*output*/ printf("Guest %d goes to the check-in reservationist\n", guestid);
        globalVar0 = guestid;
        sem_post(&s1);  // event ordering
        sem_wait(&s2);  // event ordering
        guestroom = guest_data->room;   // gets room value from struct
        /*output*/ printf("Guest %d receives Room %d and completes check-in\n", guestid, guestroom);
    sem_post(&check_in); // event ordering. Check-In now available

    sem_wait(&randSem);
    gevent = getRandomLessThan(4);  // activity connected to 0, 1, 2, 3
    printf("\tEvent: %d\n", gevent);
    sem_post(&randSem);
    printf("Guest: %d\tEvent: %d\n", guestid, gevent);
    guest_data[guestid].event = gevent; // assign to Guest's struct

    switch(gevent)
    {
        case(0):
            /*output*/ printf("Guest %d: Go to hotel swimming pool\n", guestid);
            pool++;
            break;

        case(1):
            /*output*/ printf("Guest %d: Go to hotel resturant\n", guestid);
            resturant++;
            break;

        case(2):
            /*output*/ printf("Guest %d: Go to hotel fitness center\n", guestid);
            fitness_center++;
            break;

        case(3):
            /*output*/ printf("Guest %d: Go to hotel business center\n", guestid);
            business_center++;
            break;
    }

    sem_wait(&randSem);
    sleepVal = getRandomLessThan(3) + 1;
    printf("\tSleepVal: %d\n", sleepVal);
    sem_post(&randSem);
    printf("Guest %d sleeps for %d seconds\n", guestid, sleepVal);
    sleep(1); // 0-2 + 1 = 1-3 //Change back

    /*output*/ printf("Guest %d waits for check-out\n", guestid);
    sem_wait(&check_out); // guest waits for check-out desk to be available
        /*output*/ printf("Guest %d goes to the check-out reservationist and returns room %d\n", guestid, guestroom);
        globalVar1 = guestid;
        //globalVar2 = guestroom;
        sem_post(&s3); // event ordering
        sem_wait(&s4); // event ordering

        gcost = guest_data[guestid].cost;
        /*output*/ printf("Guest %d receives the total balance of $%d\n", guestid, gcost);
        /*output*/ printf("Guest %d makes a payment\n", guestid);
        sem_post(&s5); // event ordering
        sem_wait(&s6); // event ordering
    sem_post(&check_out);

    total_guests++;

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int getRandomLessThan(int x)
{
    int r = -1;
    srand(time(NULL));
    r = rand() % x;
    //printf("\tRandom number: %d\n", r);

    return r;
}

int GetOpenRoom()
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) // rooms.size and rooms.length throw errors
    {
        if (rooms[i] == 1) // room available
        {
            rooms[i] = 0; // set to unavailable
            return i;
        }
    }
}

int RoomAvailable()
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        if (rooms[i] == 1) // room available
            return 1;
    }
    return 0; // if none available, return 0
}

void *CheckIn(void *guestData)
{
    int i, guestid, guestroom;

    for(i=0; i<NUM_GUESTS; i++)
    {
        sem_wait(&s1); // event ordering

        guestid = globalVar0; // get the global variable set to the guestID
        /*output*/ printf("The check-in reservationist greets Guest %d\n", guestid);

        sem_wait(&roomArraySem);
        guestroom = GetOpenRoom(); // method returns index of open room
        sem_post(&roomArraySem);
        thread_data_array[guestid].room = guestroom; // assign room to guest

        /*output*/ printf("Assign room %d to Guest %d\n", guestroom, guestid);

        sem_post(&s2); // event ordering
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


void *CheckOut(void *guestData)
{
    int i, guestid, guestroom, gcost;

    for(i=0; i<NUM_GUESTS; i++)
    {
        sem_wait(&s3); // event ordering

        guestid = globalVar1;
        //guestroom = globalVar2;
        guestroom = thread_data_array[guestid].room;

        /*output*/ printf("The check-out greets Guest %d and receives the key from room %d\n", guestid, guestroom);
        sem_wait(&roomArraySem);
        rooms[guestroom] = 1; // room now available, set back to 1
        sem_post(&roomArraySem);
        sem_post(&roomSem); // release a room

        /*output*/ printf("Calculate the balance for Guest %d\n", guestid);
        gcost = getRandomLessThan(300) + 50;        // 50 < cost < 350
        thread_data_array[guestid].cost = gcost;

        sem_post(&s4); // event ordering
        sem_wait(&s5); // event ordering
        /*output*/ printf("Receive $%d from Guest %d and complete the check-out\n", gcost, guestid);
        sem_post(&s6); // event ordering
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}



int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rc, rc1, rc2;
    int guest;
    int check;
    //struct thread_data *guest_data; //delete?

    sem_init(&roomSem, 1, 5); //not 0 means shared between multiple processes, 5 is initial value
    sem_init(&check_in, 1, 1);
    sem_init(&check_out, 1, 1);
    sem_init(&s1, 1, 0);
    sem_init(&s2, 1, 0);
    sem_init(&s3, 1, 0);
    sem_init(&s4, 1, 0);
    sem_init(&s5, 1, 0);
    sem_init(&s6, 1, 0);
    sem_init(&roomArraySem, 1, 1);
    sem_init(&randSem, 1, 1);

    rc1 = pthread_create(&desk[0], NULL, CheckIn, NULL);    // Check In runs on it's own now
    rc2 = pthread_create(&desk[1], NULL, CheckOut, NULL);   // Check Out runs on it's own now

    if(rc1){
        printf("ERROR; return code from desk0 is %d\n\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
    }
    if(rc2){
        printf("ERROR; return code from desk1 is %d\n\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
    }

    for(guest = 0; guest < NUM_GUESTS; guest++)
    {
        thread_data_array[guest].guest_id = guest; // guest ID for each guest thread
        /*Output*/printf("Main(): Creating Thread: %d\n", guest);
        rc = pthread_create(&guests[guest], NULL, Guest, (void *)&thread_data_array[guest]); //Guest method, &thread_data_array[guest] argument
        if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create(Guest) is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    printf("\tDONE WITH THREADS\n");

    for(guest = 0; guest < NUM_GUESTS; guest++)
    {
        pthread_join(guests[guest], NULL); // waits for each guest to complete and cleans memory space
    }
    printf("\tBETWEEN THREAD JOINS 1\n");

    pthread_join(desk[0], NULL);
    printf("\tBETWEEN THREAD JOINS 2\n");
    pthread_join(desk[1], NULL);
    printf("\tBETWEEN THREAD JOINS 3\n");

    printf("\t\tNumber of Customers\n");
    printf("Total Guests:\t\t%d\n", total_guests);
    printf("Pool:\t\t\t%d\n", pool);
    printf("Resturant:\t\t%d\n", resturant);
    printf("Fitness Center:\t\t%d\n", fitness_center);
    printf("Business Center:\t%d\n", business_center);

    sem_close(&roomSem);
    sem_close(&check_in);
    sem_close(&check_out);
    sem_close(&s1);
    sem_close(&s2);
    sem_close(&s3);
    sem_close(&s4);
    sem_close(&s5);
    sem_close(&s6);
    sem_close(&roomArraySem);
    sem_close(&randSem);

}
```

---

Here's what the console returns:

```
tames@lab17:~/Desktop/project2$ gcc -pthread HotelProject_v4.c
tames@lab17:~/Desktop/project2$ ./a.out
Main(): Creating Thread: 0
Main(): Creating Thread: 1
Main(): Creating Thread: 2
Guest 1 waits for check-in
Main(): Creating Thread: 3
Guest 1 goes to the check-in reservationist
Main(): Creating Thread: 4
Guest 3 waits for check-in
The check-in reservationist greets Guest 1
Assign room 0 to Guest 1
Guest 2 waits for check-in
Guest 1 receives Room 0 and completes check-in
Guest 0 waits for check-in
Main(): Creating Thread: 5
Guest 4 waits for check-in
Guest 5 waits for check-in
Guest 3 goes to the check-in reservationist
Guest 1: Go to hotel fitness center
Guest 1 sleeps for 1 seconds
The check-in reservationist greets Guest 3
Assign room 1 to Guest 3
Main(): Creating Thread: 6
Guest 3 receives Room 1 and completes check-in
Main(): Creating Thread: 7
Guest 3: Go to hotel fitness center
Main(): Creating Thread: 8
Guest 6 waits for check-in
Guest 3 sleeps for 1 seconds
Guest 2 goes to the check-in reservationist
Guest 7 waits for check-in
Main(): Creating Thread: 9
Guest 8 waits for check-in
        DONE WITH THREADS
The check-in reservationist greets Guest 2
Assign room 2 to Guest 2
Guest 9 waits for check-in
Guest 2 receives Room 2 and completes check-in
Guest 2: Go to hotel fitness center
Guest 0 goes to the check-in reservationist
The check-in reservationist greets Guest 0
Assign room 3 to Guest 0
Guest 2 sleeps for 1 seconds
Guest 0 receives Room 3 and completes check-in
Guest 4 goes to the check-in reservationist
Guest 0: Go to hotel fitness center
The check-in reservationist greets Guest 4
Assign room 4 to Guest 4
Guest 0 sleeps for 1 seconds
Guest 4 receives Room 4 and completes check-in
Guest 4: Go to hotel fitness center
Guest 5 goes to the check-in reservationist
Guest 4 sleeps for 1 seconds
Guest 1 waits for check-out
Guest 1 goes to the check-out reservationist and returns room 0
The check-out greets Guest 1 and receives the key from room 0
Calculate the balance for Guest 1
The check-in reservationist greets Guest 5
Assign room 0 to Guest 5
Guest 1 receives the total balance of $0
Guest 1 makes a payment
Guest 5 receives Room 0 and completes check-in
Guest 5: Go to hotel fitness center
Guest 6 goes to the check-in reservationist
Receive $58 from Guest 1 and complete the check-out
Guest 5 sleeps for 2 seconds
Guest 3 waits for check-out
Guest 3 goes to the check-out reservationist and returns room 1
The check-out greets Guest 3 and receives the key from room 1
Calculate the balance for Guest 3
The check-in reservationist greets Guest 6
Assign room 1 to Guest 6
Guest 3 receives the total balance of $0
Guest 3 makes a payment
Guest 6 receives Room 1 and completes check-in
Guest 2 waits for check-out
Receive $58 from Guest 3 and complete the check-out
Guest 7 goes to the check-in reservationist
Guest 2 goes to the check-out reservationist and returns room 2
Guest 6: Go to hotel fitness center
The check-out greets Guest 2 and receives the key from room 2
Calculate the balance for Guest 2
Guest 0 waits for check-out
Guest 6 sleeps for 2 seconds
The check-in reservationist greets Guest 7
Guest 2 receives the total balance of $0
Guest 2 makes a payment
Assign room 2 to Guest 7
Receive $58 from Guest 2 and complete the check-out
Guest 7 receives Room 2 and completes check-in
Guest 7: Go to hotel fitness center
Guest 8 goes to the check-in reservationist
Guest 7 sleeps for 2 seconds
Guest 0 goes to the check-out reservationist and returns room 3
Guest 4 waits for check-out
The check-out greets Guest 0 and receives the key from room 3
Calculate the balance for Guest 0
Guest 0 receives the total balance of $58
Guest 0 makes a payment
Receive $58 from Guest 0 and complete the check-out
The check-in reservationist greets Guest 8
Assign room 3 to Guest 8
Guest 4 goes to the check-out reservationist and returns room 4
Guest 8 receives Room 3 and completes check-in
Guest 8: Go to hotel fitness center
Guest 9 goes to the check-in reservationist
Guest 8 sleeps for 2 seconds
The check-out greets Guest 4 and receives the key from room 4
Calculate the balance for Guest 4
The check-in reservationist greets Guest 9
Assign room 4 to Guest 9
Guest 4 receives the total balance of $0
Guest 4 makes a payment
Guest 9 receives Room 4 and completes check-in
Receive $58 from Guest 4 and complete the check-out
Guest 9: Go to hotel fitness center
Guest 9 sleeps for 2 seconds
Guest 5 waits for check-out
Guest 5 goes to the check-out reservationist and returns room 0
The check-out greets Guest 5 and receives the key from room 0
Calculate the balance for Guest 5
Guest 5 receives the total balance of $0
Guest 5 makes a payment
Receive $293 from Guest 5 and complete the check-out
Guest 6 waits for check-out
Guest 6 goes to the check-out reservationist and returns room 1
Guest 7 waits for check-out
The check-out greets Guest 6 and receives the key from room 1
Calculate the balance for Guest 6
Guest 6 receives the total balance of $0
Guest 6 makes a payment
Receive $293 from Guest 6 and complete the check-out
Guest 8 waits for check-out
Guest 7 goes to the check-out reservationist and returns room 2
Guest 9 waits for check-out
The check-out greets Guest 7 and receives the key from room 2
Calculate the balance for Guest 7
Guest 7 receives the total balance of $32604
Guest 7 makes a payment
Receive $293 from Guest 7 and complete the check-out
Guest 8 goes to the check-out reservationist and returns room 3
The check-out greets Guest 8 and receives the key from room 3
Calculate the balance for Guest 8
Guest 8 receives the total balance of $0
Guest 8 makes a payment
Receive $293 from Guest 8 and complete the check-out
Guest 9 goes to the check-out reservationist and returns room 4
The check-out greets Guest 9 and receives the key from room 4
Calculate the balance for Guest 9
Guest 9 receives the total balance of $0
Guest 9 makes a payment
Receive $293 from Guest 9 and complete the check-out
        BETWEEN THREAD JOINS 1
        BETWEEN THREAD JOINS 2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: I just compiled and ran your program and I don't get a segfault. Do you get it every time? What is the version of gcc that you're using (gcc --version)?

Comment: Also, it will help if you include your output in your question (including error).

Comment: @stanm I do get the error every time I run it. The computer I compile/execute on returns "gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4  
I have added the Output in my question.

Comment: It seems that there are race conditions taking place. The program sometimes crashes for me, sometimes it doesn't. Currently, it is stuck by both check-in and check-out waiting on semaphores (s1 and s3, resp), one guest waiting on s2, and three guests waiting on check_in.

Comment: @stanm I am picking up on that as well, where sometimes I receive a SegFault, while others, it hangs forever after a "Guest completes check-out".

Comment: @stanm I've found that the issue most likely lies in the `array[5]` of rooms being accessed by the guests.  I say this because when I turn down the `NUM_GUESTS` to 4 it works fine. 5 and above cause the SegFault. The total number of rooms available are 5. I'm not sure why this happens but I've gotten closer to finding the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110577/discussion-between-stanm-and-tawm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is line 71:

```
guest_data[guestid].event = gevent; // assign to Guest's struct
```

`guest_data` is already offset when being passed to the `Guest` function in `main`:

```
rc = pthread_create(&guests[guest], NULL, Guest, (void *)&thread_data_array[guest]); //Guest method, &thread_data_array[guest] argument
```

For this reason, line 71 should instead read:

```
guest_data->event = gevent; // assign to Guest's struct
```

or (not tested):

```
thread_data_array[guestid].event = gevent;
```

The segfault actually occurs in one of the threads, but unfortunately is manifested only during calls in pthread making it harder to localize and debug. Check out the discussion: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110577/discussion-between-stanm-and-tawm

A question that might be related: [C++ libpthread program segfaults for unknown reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312194/c-libpthread-program-segfaults-for-unknown-reason)

Answer (score 0):

valgrind aborts:

> ==8635== Process terminating with default action of signal 6 (SIGABRT)
>   ==8635==    at 0x508C418: raise (raise.c:54)
>   ==8635==    by 0x508E019: abort (abort.c:89)
>   ==8635==    by 0x50CE729: __libc_message (libc_fatal.c:175)
>   ==8635==    by 0x50CE74D: __libc_fatal (libc_fatal.c:185)
>   ==8635==    by 0x4E49C8D: futex_fatal_error (futex-internal.h:200)
>   ==8635==    by 0x4E49C8D: futex_wake (futex-internal.h:247)
>   ==8635==    by 0x4E49C8D: sem_post@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (sem_post.c:57)
>   ==8635==    by 0x400A16: Guest (in /home/oem/test99)
>   ==8635==    by 0x4E416F9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)

restarting with helgrind, reveals more problems (data used without locks, causes cache-problems), these there are many of

> ==8774== Possible data race during read of size 4 at 0x6020A0 by thread #5
>   ==8774== Locks held: none
>   ==8774==    at 0x400CB4: RoomAvailable (in /home/oem/test99)
>   ==8774==    by 0x4009CD: Guest (in /home/oem/test99)
>   ==8774==    by 0x4C34DB6: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-  amd64-linux.so)
>   ==8774==    by 0x4E476F9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
>   ==8774==
>   ==8774== This conflicts with a previous write of size 4 by thread #2
>   ==8774== Locks held: none
>   ==8774==    at 0x400C86: GetOpenRoom (in /home/oem/test99)
>   ==8774==    by 0x400D27: CheckIn (in /home/oem/test99)
>   ==8774==    by 0x4C34DB6: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
>   ==8774==    by 0x4E476F9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
>   ==8774==  Address 0x6020a0 is 0 bytes inside data symbol "rooms"