# How do I know which illegal address the program access when a segmentation fault happens

Tags: c, linux, embedded, segmentation-fault

Plus, The program runs on a arm device running Linux， I can print out stack info and register values in the sig-seg handler I assign.
The problem is I can't add -g option to the source file, since the bug may won't reproduce due to performance downgrade.

Comment: At least with GCC you can add -g without disabling optimization. And on ELF targets, GCC puts the debug info into separate sections, so they won't even be loaded from disk until needed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Compiling with the `-g` option to `gcc` does *not* cause a "performance downgrade".  All it does is cause debugging symbols to be included; it does *not* affect the optimisation or code generation.

If you install your `SIGSEGV` handler using the `sa_sigaction` member of the `sigaction` struct passed to `sigaction()`, then the `si_addr` member of the `siginfo_t` structure passed to your handler contains the faulting address.

Comment: I Have had issues where a segfault that was caused by writing to an un-initialized pointer appeared and disappeared depending on whether I used -g, or what -o level I had. It has to do with what memory is where. Similarly, I've had it where adding or deleting a printf made the error appear. segfaults in C can be wily bastards.

Answer (score 4):

I tend to use `valgrind` which indicates leaks and *memory access faults*.

Comment: valgrind is for X86, AMD64 and PPC - the questioner is running on ARM. However I am pleasantly surprised to read that ARM support is in progress.

Comment: @crazyscot I indeed missed the "arm" part of the question. But nice to know valgrind is about to support this architecture ;)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work
http://tlug.up.ac.za/wiki/index.php/Obtaining_a_stack_trace_in_C_upon_SIGSEGV

```
static void signal_segv(int signum, siginfo_t* info, void*ptr) {
// info->si_addr is the illegal address
}
```

Comment: `info->si_addr` is the faulting memory address.  As noted in the link you provided, the address at the time the signal was raised can be retrieved from `void * ptr`.  See my answer here for code I have used with ARM - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes/1925461#1925461

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about using -g on the binary that you load on the device, you may be able to use gdbserver on the ARM device with a stripped version of the executable and run arm-gdb on your development machine with the unstripped version of the executable.  The stripped version and the unstripped version need to match up to do this, so do this:

```
# You may add your own optimization flags
arm-gcc -g program.c -o program.debug 
arm-strip --strip-debug program.debug -o program
# or
arm-strip --strip-unneeded program.debug -o program
```

You'll need to read the gdb and gdbserver documentation to figure out how to use them.  It's not that difficult, but it isn't as polished as it could be.  Mainly it's very easy to accidentally tell gdb to do something that it ends up thinking you meant to do locally, so it will switch out of remote debugging mode.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to use the backtrace() function if available, that will provide the call stack at the time of the crash. This can be used in order to dump the stack like it happens in an high level programming language when a C program gets a segmentation fault, bus error, or other memory violation error.

backtrace() is available both on Linux and Mac OS X

Answer (score 0):

If the -g option makes the error disappear, then knowing where it crashes is unlikely to be useful anyway. It's probably writing to an uninitialized pointer in function A, and then function B tries to legitimately use that memory, and dies. Memory errors are a pain.