# Getting fault address that generated a UNIX signal

Tags: c++, unix, signals

I am interested in a signal handler which can identify the address of the instruction which caused the problem.

I know about `siginfo_t` and `__builtin_return_address` and neither seem to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>

void handler (int, siginfo_t *, void *);

int main ()
{
begin:
    std :: cerr << &&begin << " ~ " << &&before << " ~ " << &&after << "\n";

    struct sigaction s;
    s .sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigemptyset (& s .sa_mask);
    s .sa_sigaction = handler;
    sigaction (SIGSEGV, &s, NULL);

    int * i = NULL;
before:
    *i = 0;
after:
    std :: cout << "End.\n";
}

void handler (int, siginfo_t *si, void *)
{
    std :: cerr << "si:" << si -> si_addr << "\n";
    std :: cerr << "At: " << __builtin_return_address (0) << "\n";
    std :: cerr << "At: " << __builtin_return_address (1) << "\n";
    std :: cerr << "At: " << __builtin_return_address (2) << "\n";
    std :: cerr << "At: " << __builtin_return_address (3) << "\n";
    std :: cerr << "At: " << __builtin_return_address (4) << "\n";
    std :: cerr << "At: " << __builtin_return_address (5) << "\n";
}
```

This outputs something like:

```
0x10978 ~ 0x10a4c ~ 0x10a54
si:0
At: 0xfb945364
At: 0xfb939e64
At: 0x10a40
At: 0x10740
At: 0
At: Segmentation Fault
```

So `siginfo_t` is NULL and `__builtin_return_address` is yielding values somewhere *in between* the named labels.

I was expecting both of these to return the value of `&&before`. Am I using these functions correctly?

Tested on Linux 2.6.9-89.0.9.Elsmp and SunOS.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes/1925461#1925461) to [How to generate a stacktrace when my gcc C++ app crashes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/77005/203667) may be of use.

Comment: Remember that another process can send a signal to this process, so the 'fault address' may not tell you anything significant.  OTOH, that is a fairly unlikely event.

Comment: @Jonathan: with realtime signals (`sigaction` with `SA_SIGINFO` and `siginfo_t`), the kernel is requires to protect against spoofing. There's a field in the `siginfo_t` which tells the source of the signal, and `sigqueue` cannot fake the source as kernel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The third argument to a handler installed with `SA_SIGINFO` (the one declared as `void *`) is a pointer to a `ucontext_t` structure.  The contents of this structure are architecture- and OS-specific and not part of any standard, but they include the information you need.  Here's a version of your program adapted to use it (Linux/x86-64 specific; you *will* need `#ifdef`s for every architecture and OS of interest):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <signal.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

using std::cout;

static volatile int *causecrash;

static void handler(int, siginfo_t *si, void *ptr)
{
   ucontext_t *uc = (ucontext_t *)ptr;

   cout << "si:" << si->si_addr << '\n';
   cout << "ip:" << std::hex << uc->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP] << '\n';
}

int main()
{
begin:
    cout.setf(std::ios::unitbuf);
    cout << &&begin << " ~ " << &&before << " ~ " << &&after << '\n';

    struct sigaction s;
    s.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO|SA_RESETHAND;
    s.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sigemptyset(&s.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &s, 0);

before:
    *causecrash = 0;
after:
    cout << "End.\n";
}
```

By the way, GCC has this nasty habit of moving labels whose address is taken but not used in a control transfer operation (as far as it can tell).  Compare:

```
$ g++ -O0 -W -Wall test.cc && ./a.out 
0x400a30 ~ 0x400acd ~ 0x400ada
si:0
ip:400ad4
Segmentation fault
$ g++ -O2 -W -Wall test.cc && ./a.out 
0x4009f0 ~ 0x4009f0 ~ 0x4009f0
si:0
ip:400ab4
Segmentation fault
```

See how all the labels are at the same address in the optimized version? That's going to trip up any attempt to, say, recover from the fault by adjusting the PC.  IIRC there is a way to make GCC not do that, but I don't know what it is and wasn't able to find it in the manual.

Comment: Trying to recover from the fault by adjusting the PC is getting into dangerous undefined behavior land.  You can try to `longjmp` out to a known piece of code, but even that could be fraught with peril; the best option really is to dump core and die.

Comment: @Adam: You can `mmap` something new over top of the address of the failed access, then return. This could be a viable solution to `SIGSEGV` or `SIGBUS` from truncated mmapped files, overcommit, etc.

Comment: True, but at the same time, it's a thing that people really do and can often make work reliably enough for their purposes.   For instance, persistent object databases and GC write barriers often pull such tricks.  (I don't know of anyone relying on GCC address-of-label extensions for it, though.)

Comment: @R You don't need to tweak the PC for that (I agree it's less fraught with peril)

Answer (score 2):

The `siginfo_t` isn't going to work because [it contains the memory address which was accessed](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man5/siginfo_t.5.asp), not the address of the instruction that did it.

Now, the `__builtin_return_address` is interesting. On my machine it returns some nonsense:

```
0x40089f ~ 0x400935 ~ 0x40093f
si:0
At: 0x7fe22916fc20
At: 0x7fe22915ad8e
```

I have no idea why. But then I examined the core dump:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004009ff in handler(int, siginfo*, void*) ()
#1  <signal handler called>
#2  0x0000000000400939 in main ()
```

As you can see, just like in your case, the offending address is somewhere in between label locations. This is easily explained, though. Just look at the disassembly of main():

```
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   ...
   ; the label is here:
   0x0000000000400935 <+161>:   mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
=> 0x0000000000400939 <+165>:   movl   $0x0,(%rax)
   0x000000000040093f <+171>:   mov    $0x400c32,%esi
```

The labelled statement consists of several instructions. The first one loads the address into the RAX register. It completes successfully because there is nothing wrong with it. It's the second one that accesses the address and breaks. This explains why the address in your trace is a bit different from the address of the label, although the code will probably be different from my example. This all doesn't explain why the `__builtin_return_address` gives nonsense in my case, though.

Comment: `__builtin_return_address`, when called with any nonzero argument, assumes the existence of a frame-pointer chain.  This is not required by x86-64, and even if you force the compiler to generate one, the special "caller of signal handler" frame that the kernel fabricates will break the chain.