# Is there any library in C like python's inspect?

Tags: python, c

Is there any library in C like python's inspect?

```
def myfunction():
   import inspect
   inspect.stack(): # this give you complete stack up to this function call
```

It's very useful to debug python program.

Actually I want to debug GTK Combobox widget, to understand complete flow I need complete function call stack.

So is there any similar library of Technic in C language like python inspect package?

Comment: You can use GDB to get a stack trace. Otherwise see this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes

Answer (score 2):

No such portable library exists. There's a [solution](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Backtraces.html) specific to GNU `libc`.