# Stacktrace for C on Android

Tags: android, c, stack-trace

I have C code in my Android app and would like to catch crashes and print them to a log file. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes), and tried, but I can't find the execinfo lib. 
I'm working with Ubuntu 11.10 and using NDK for compiling to Android. 
Does anyone know how to find execinfo lib for NDK/ARM, or have another simple solution?

Answer (score 4):

On Android, you have some sample specials utils code allowing to see and/or dump the stack.

Implementation is in [base/libs/utils/CallStack.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/gingerbread/libs/utils/CallStack.cpp). You'll a find a [tiny sample code here](http://funsung.blogspot.com/2009/08/android-show-call-stack.html).

Comment: I don't get it, how to I obtain the lib with CallStack? Where's the H file? How do I use it? The tiny sample doesn't really say enough... Can you elaborate?