# What are the pros and cons of collecting libc backtrace always?

Tags: gdb, glibc, backtrace

As the question states, is it useful to *always* collect a software-based backtrace (like using libc backtrace http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html ) in all error functions and signal handlers ?

Would it not be very helpful for debugging a wide variety of bugs like memory, concurrency bugs etc. ? I guess it would not hurt normal performance as well as it will be triggered only in error paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As the question states, is it useful to always collect a software-based backtrace

Yes, it is generally very useful to have a crash stack trace when:

- your code runs in your own environment, and you are not worried about the stack trace revealing any secrets.
- when the crash handler does not further corrupt the coredump, does not hang, etc.

> like using libc backtrace

glibc `backtrace` calls `calloc` under certain conditions, and is not safe in a crash handler. It can cause both the hang, and the further corruption mentioned above. Writing a crash handler that will reliably print stack trace in async-signal-safe manner is quite non-trivial.

> why then do error functions in "standard" applications not call backtrace?

Consider `cat /no/such/file`. Currently it produces:

```
cat: /no/such/file: No such file or directory
```

which is *all* you really need to know. Making this print anything else is useless. If you had many such files, and  cat printed a full stack trace for each, you'd get many pages of error output, and that would only make finding the real problem harder.

For fatal signal handlers (e.g. `SIGSEGV`) the answer is that most "standard" applications don't actually handle such signals, and simply use the default action, which produces a core dump.

But if they did catch the signal, calling `backtrace`, `backtrace_symbols`, or `backtrace_symbols_fd` from the signal handler would be equally unsafe, and could deadlock, which is much worse than simply dumping core. Consider what happens if you have a long-running script with a 1000 commands in it. You start it, and a week later discover that it didn't make any progress because the second command crashed and deadlocked trying to print the crash stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for the information ! I was wondering why then do error functions in standard applications like Coreutils don't call backtrace by default ?

Comment: @user655617 "why then do error functions ... don't call backtrace?" Do you mean error functions (e.g. "cat unreadable-file"), or do you mean crash functions? If the former, stack trace will likely just add noise. If the latter, I don't think you've understood "may cause a hang" part of the answer -- it's definitely much better to crash with no stack trace, then to (sometimes) hang indefinitely.

Comment: Hmm.. For error functions: why will stack trace just add noise ?
For crash functions : I understand your concern that backtrace() and backtrace_symbols() is not safe for calling within signal handler but can't we use backtrace_symbols_fd() to overcome this problem ?

Comment: @user655617 I've updated the answer. `backtrace_symbols_fd` is *not* any safer than `backtrace`. What made you think otherwise?

Comment: Well, I read that `backtrace_symbols_fd` does not call `malloc`, and so can be employed in situations where the latter function might fail [link](http://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace_symbols_fd) and this was also mentioned at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes#comment15654678_77005).. So, why is it also _not_ safe ? Also, I guess `ioctl` calls to a device that uses `printk` are also unsafe for signal handlers ?