# I am getting Segmentation fault while segmenting image file

Tags: c++, image, segmentation-fault, image-segmentation

I wrote the following code for processing p3.ppm type image but i am getting segmentation fault.I used prims algorithm for minimum spanning trees for the segmentation multiple times and deleting edges with minimum weight.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define INT_MAX 10e5
    using namespace std;

    bool ifvalid(int i,int j,int n,int m)
    {
        if(i<0 || i>=m || j < 0||j>=n)
            return false;
        return true;
    }


    struct cordi
    {
        int row,col;
    };
    struct pixel
    {
        int index;
        int r,g,b;
    };
    struct node
    {
        int dest,weight;
        struct node* next;
    };

    struct adjList
    {
        int s;
        node *head;
    };

    struct graph
    {
        int NumVertices;
        adjList *arr;
    };

    void addEdge(graph *g,int index,int weight,int dest)
    {
        node *newNode=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        newNode->dest=g->arr[dest].s;
        newNode->weight=weight;
        newNode->next=NULL;
        node *temp=g->arr[index].head;
        node *parent=temp;
        if(temp==NULL)
            g->arr[index].head=newNode;
        else
        {
            parent=temp;
            temp=temp->next;  
            while(temp!=NULL)
            {
                if(temp->dest==dest)
                    return;
                parent=temp;
                temp=temp->next;
            }
            parent->next=newNode;
        }
    }
    graph* generateGraph(int **r,int **g,int **b,int n,int m)
    {
        int i,j,x,y,index,dest,weight,v;
        graph *G=(graph*)malloc(sizeof(graph));
        G->NumVertices=n*m;
        v=G->NumVertices;
        G->arr=(adjList*)malloc(v *sizeof(adjList));
        int counter=0;
        for(i=0;i<v;i++)
        {
            G->arr[i].head=NULL;     
            G->arr[i].s=counter;
                counter++;
        }

        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                index=i*n+j;
                x=i+1,y=j+1;
                dest=x*n+y;
                if(ifvalid(x,y,n,m))
                {
                    weight=abs(r[i][j]-r[x][y])+abs(g[i][j]-g[x][y])+abs(b[i][j]-b[x][y]);
                    addEdge(G,index,weight,dest);
                }

                x=i+1,y=j;
                dest=x*n+y;
                if(ifvalid(x,y,n,m))
                {
                    weight=abs(r[i][j]-r[x][y])+abs(g[i][j]-g[x][y])+abs(b[i][j]-b[x][y]);
                    addEdge(G,index,weight,dest);
                }
                x=i-1,y=j;
                dest=x*n+y;
               if(ifvalid(x,y,n,m))
                {
                    weight=abs(r[i][j]-r[x][y])+abs(g[i][j]-g[x][y])+abs(b[i][j]-b[x][y]);
                    addEdge(G,index,weight,dest);
                }

                x=i,y=j+1;
                dest=x*n+y;
                if(ifvalid(x,y,n,m))
                {
                    weight=abs(r[i][j]-r[x][y])+abs(g[i][j]-g[x][y])+abs(b[i][j]-b[x][y]);
                    addEdge(G,index,weight,dest);
                }

                x=i-1,y=j+1;
                dest=x*n+y;
                if(ifvalid(x,y,n,m))
                {
                    weight=abs(r[i][j]-r[x][y])+abs(g[i][j]-g[x][y])+abs(b[i][j]-b[x][y]);
                    addEdge(G,index,weight,dest);
                }
                x=i+1,y=j-1;
                dest=x*n+y;
                if(ifvalid(x,y,n,m))
                {
                    weight=abs(r[i][j]-r[x][y])+abs(g[i][j]-g[x][y])+abs(b[i][j]-b[x][y]);
                    addEdge(G,index,weight,dest);
                }
                x=i,y=j-1;
                dest=x*n+y;
                if(ifvalid(x,y,n,m))
                {
                    weight=abs(r[i][j]-r[x][y])+abs(g[i][j]-g[x][y])+abs(b[i][j]-b[x][y]);
                    addEdge(G,index,weight,dest);
                }
                x=i-1,y=j-1;
                dest=x*n+y;
                if(ifvalid(x,y,n,m))
                {
                    weight=abs(r[i][j]-r[x][y])+abs(g[i][j]-g[x][y])+abs(b[i][j]-b[x][y]);
                    addEdge(G,index,weight,dest);
                }

            }
        }
        return G;
    }
    struct heapNode
    {
        int index;
        int key;
    };
    struct minHeap
    {
        int *pos;
        int size;    
        int capacity;     
        heapNode **arr;
    };
    minHeap* createMinHeap(int capacity)
    {
        minHeap* x=(minHeap*)malloc(sizeof(minHeap));
        x->size=0;
        x->capacity=capacity;
        x->pos=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        x->arr=(heapNode**) malloc(capacity*sizeof(heapNode*));
        return x;
    }
    void swapMinHeapNode(heapNode** a,heapNode** b)
    {
        heapNode* t = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = t;
    }

    void minHeapify(minHeap* x,int index)
    {
        int smallest,left,right;
        smallest=index;
        left=2*index+1;
        right=2*index+2;
        if (left<x->size&& x->arr[left]->key <x->arr[smallest]->key )
          smallest=left;
        if (right <x->size &&x->arr[right]->key < x->arr[smallest]->key)
          smallest = right;
        if (smallest!=index)
        {
            heapNode *smallestNode = x->arr[smallest];
            heapNode *idxNode = x->arr[index];
            x->pos[smallestNode->index]=index;
            x->pos[idxNode->index]=smallest;
            swapMinHeapNode(&x->arr[smallest],&x->arr[index]);
            minHeapify(x,smallest);
        }
    }
    int isEmpty(minHeap* x)
    {
        return x->size == 0;
    }
    heapNode* extractMin(minHeap* x)
    {
        if (isEmpty(x))
            return NULL;
        heapNode* root =x->arr[0];
        heapNode* lastNode =x->arr[x->size-1];
        x->pos[root->index] =x->size-1;
        x->pos[lastNode->index] = 0;
        x->arr[0]=lastNode;
        x->size--;
        minHeapify(x,0);
        return root;
    }
    void decreaseKey(minHeap* x,int index,int key)
    {
        int i =x->pos[index];
        x->arr[i]->key = key;
        while (i && x->arr[i]->key <x->arr[(i-1)/2]->key)
        {
            x->pos[x->arr[i]->index] = (i-1)/2;
            x->pos[x->arr[(i-1)/2]->index]=i;
            swapMinHeapNode(&x->arr[i],&x->arr[(i-1)/2]);
            i=(i-1)/2;
        }
    }
    bool isInMinHeap(minHeap *x, int index)
    {
       if (x->pos[index] <x->size)
         return true;
       return false;
    }
    graph* PrimMST(graph* g)
    {
        graph *mstGraph=(graph*)malloc(sizeof(graph));
        mstGraph->NumVertices=g->NumVertices;

        int counter=0;
        int V=g->NumVertices;
        mstGraph->arr=(adjList*)malloc(V*sizeof(adjList));
        for(int i=0;i<V;i++)
        {
            mstGraph->arr[i].head=NULL;     
            mstGraph->arr[i].s=counter;
                counter++;
        }
        int *parent=(int *)malloc(V*sizeof(int));
        int *key=(int *)malloc(V*sizeof(int ));
        minHeap *x=createMinHeap(V);
        for (int v=1; v < V; ++v)
        {
            parent[v]=-1;
            key[v] = INT_MAX;
            heapNode *e=(heapNode *)malloc(sizeof(heapNode));
            e->index=v;
            e->key=key[v];
            x->arr[v]=e;
            x->pos[v]=v;
        }
        heapNode *e=(heapNode *)malloc(sizeof(heapNode));
        e->index=0;
        key[0]=0;
        parent[0]=-1;
        e->key=0;
        x->arr[0]=e;
        x->pos[0]=0;
        x->size = V;
        while (!isEmpty(x))
        {
            heapNode* mini=extractMin(x);
            int u=mini->index;
            node* pCrawl=g->arr[u].head;
            while (pCrawl!=NULL)
            {
                int v=pCrawl->dest;
                if (pCrawl->weight<key[v])
                {
                    parent[v]=u;
                    key[v]=pCrawl->weight;
                    decreaseKey(x,v,key[v]);
                }
                pCrawl=pCrawl->next;
            }
        }
        for(int i=1;i<V;i++)
        {
            if(parent[i]!=-1){
                addEdge(mstGraph,i,key[i],parent[i]);
                addEdge(mstGraph,parent[i],key[i],i);}
        }
        return mstGraph;
    }
    int maxi=-1,vertex1,vertex2;
    void dfs(graph *mstGraph,bool *visited,int s)
    {
        visited[s]=true;
        node *temp=mstGraph->arr[s].head;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            int v=temp->dest;
            //printf("%d\n",v);
            if(!visited[v])
            {
                if(temp->weight>maxi)
                {
                    maxi=temp->weight;
                    vertex1=s;
                    vertex2=v;
                }
                dfs(mstGraph,visited,v);
            }
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
    void dfsColor(graph *mstGraph,int color,bool *visited,int s,pixel *li)
    {
        visited[s]=true;
        li[s].index=s;
        li[s].r=color;
        li[s].g=color;
        li[s].b=color;
        node *temp=mstGraph->arr[s].head;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            int v=temp->dest;
            if(!visited[v])
                dfsColor(mstGraph,color,visited,v,li);
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
    void deleteEdge(graph *mstGraph)
    {

        node *temp=mstGraph->arr[vertex2].head;
        node *parent;
        if(temp->dest==vertex1)
            mstGraph->arr[vertex2].head=temp->next;
        else
        {
            parent=temp;
            temp=temp->next;
            while(temp!=NULL)
            {
                if(temp->dest==vertex1)
                {
                    parent->next=temp->next;
                    break;
               }
               else
               {
                parent=temp;
                temp=temp->next;
               }
            }
        }
         printf("dgz\n");
        temp=mstGraph->arr[vertex1].head;
        if(temp->dest==vertex2)
            mstGraph->arr[vertex1].head=temp->next;
        else
        {
            parent=temp;
            temp=temp->next;
            while(temp!=NULL)
            {
                if(temp->dest==vertex2)
                {
                    parent->next=temp->next;
                    break;
               }
               else
               {
                parent=temp;
                temp=temp->next;
               }
            }
        }
    }
    int main()
    {
        srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
        FILE *ip,*op;
        ip=fopen("original.ppm","r");
        op=fopen("generated.ppm","w");
        char fileType[100];
        fscanf(ip,"%s",fileType);
        int n,m,i,j;
        fscanf(ip,"%d%d",&n,&m);
        int **r=(int**)malloc(m*sizeof(int *));
        int **g=(int**)malloc(m*sizeof(int *));
        int **b=(int**)malloc(m*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            r[i]=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
            b[i]=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
            g[i]=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        }
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                fscanf(ip,"%d%d%d",&r[i][j],&g[i][j],&b[i][j]);
            }
        }
        int color=0,s=3;
        graph *G=generateGraph(r,g,b,n,m);
        int v=G->NumVertices;
        bool *visited=(bool *)malloc(v*sizeof(bool));
        pixel *li=(pixel *)malloc(v*sizeof(pixel));
        graph *mstGraph=PrimMST(G);


        for(i=0;i<s-1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<v;j++)
                visited[j]=false;

            dfs(mstGraph,visited,0);
            deleteEdge(mstGraph);
        }

        for(int j=0;j<v;j++)
                visited[j]=false;
        color=0;
        for(i=0;i<v;i++)
        {
            if(!visited[i])
            {
                color++;
                dfsColor(mstGraph,color,visited,i,li);
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n",color);
        fprintf(op,"%s\n",fileType);
        fprintf(op,"%d %d\n",n,m);
        for(i=0;i<v;i++)
        {
           fprintf(op,"%d\n",li[i].r);
            fprintf(op,"%d\n",li[i].g);
          fprintf(op,"%d\n",li[i].b);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can't you use the debugger to find out where the segmentation fault occurs?

Comment: it will be an attempt to access an array element out of bounds

Comment: With this huge amount of indexes and arrays, probably you're getting out of bounds.

Comment: A 450-line code wall that you should run under a debugger before ever thinking about posting it here? yeah... moving on.

Comment: You never free memory allocated with malloc().

Answer (score 2):

You should run `gcc <yourfilename>.cpp -lstdc++ -g -o myoutput`

then use:

```
gdb ./myoutput
```

and then type run.

You will see your stackoverflow:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804927d in minHeapify (x=0x804dc60, index=0) at segfault.cpp:186
186     if (leftsize&& x->arr[left]->key arr[smallest]->key )

that means that you are going out of boundaries in your `void minHeapify(minHeap* x,int index)` function.

You can dump your crashes installing a sighandler in your code which makes use of backtrace and backtrace_symbols (you will find a lot of examples like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes)) and then passing the result to [addr2line](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/addr2line.html).

Comment: If it were possible to pick something *less* related to the OP's fault issue from the 450 lines of fish in a barrel, I'm pressed to think of it. And [`time(NULL)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) is fully supported by the standard library, so on top of being unrelated, this answer is also inaccurate in even being problematic.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/2/time not supported here.

Comment: Did you miss the sentence : "If t is non-NULL, the return value is also stored in the memory pointed to by t." ?

Comment: sorry @WhozCraig ... that wasn't me. It won't happen anymore.

Comment: response changed to something that has a sense

Comment: Considerably moreso =P +1