# How to avoid writing a core file and speed-up the backtrace generation

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, coredump

Before I ask my question I describe briefly how I get backtrace from my clients.
I write a C++ application on linux (opensuse).

This application is launched by a script (the launcher), and if the application crashes, a core dump is generated (because ulimit -c unlimited).
Then the launcher generates a backtrace from the core file whith gdb, and starts again the application, which gives the possibility to the user to send a crash report containing the backtrace.

Now my problem and my question :

- **the problem** : the core dump can be quite big (up to 5 or 10 GB). The copy of the core file takes a certain time (up to 2 minutes). This is a problem for my clients : it's too long between the crash and the application auto-restart.
- **the question** : I generate the backtrace with gdb from 1) my program 2) the core file.
  When the application crashes, a custom script is called by [Piping core dumps to a program](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) : could I, in this program, direclty attach gdb to the "dying" program and generate the backtrace earning the time to copy the core file on the HDD ?

Thanks in advance.

Just a remark:

- I did all I can to reduce to the minimum the size of the core dump (no debug symbol, only dump what is needed for a backtrace (see [Controlling which mappings are written to the core dump](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html)))

Comment: Have you tried to reduce debug information when building? I mean, for example, using `-g1` instead of `-g`; and optimization `-O1` or `-O2`

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to add whole `gdb` just to do backtrace of crashing program. Just intercept signal like SIGBUS and when signalled you can use [backtrace()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace) or simply call gstack with pid of your program.

Comment: **Should not work reliably.** Since `backtrace` is not async-signal-safe. See [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent answer in how to obtain a stacktrace without generating a core dump  in copy/paste form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes).

It will generate a stacktrace to stderr, but you could easily do something different like post the stacktrace data using HTTP etc.