# Getting the "real" function from a method pointer

Tags: c++, portability, introspection, debug-symbols

Given an c++ object pointer and compatible method pointer to a virtual method, is there any remotely robust/portable way to get a pointer to the actual concert function that would be called?

The use case is that I want to run said pointer thought the debug symbols to get the name of the type/function that would be called (without actually calling it).

If this is only possible via implementation specific solutions, then I'm primarily interested in supporting GCC/LLVM.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes . It might help.

Comment: @cup looks like that covers the "given pointer, get usable string" bit that I already know more or less how to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Both LLVM and GCC follow the [Itanium C++ ABI](http://www.swag.uwaterloo.ca/acd/docs/ItaniumC++ABI.htm), so you need to find a way to read the data structures as specified therein.   I'll give a rough outline. 
A pointer to virtual member is represented by an offset into the virtual function table, +1 for some reason.

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void f();
    virtual void g();
};

void (A::*pAg)() = & A::g;
ptrdiff_t offset = *(ptrdiff_t*)(&pAg) - 1;
```

The pointer to the virtual table is typically located right at the beginning of an object:

```
A a;
void* vtable = *(void**)&a;
```

Then you look at the calculated offset within that virtual table and find your actual function pointer.

```
void* function = *(void**)(vtable+offset)
```

Comment: I'll give that a try as soon as I give up m forlorn hope of a portable solution showing up.