# STDERR_FILENO undeclared on ubuntu

Tags: c, stdio

I'm trying to compile [an example stack trace displaying code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77336). When I compile the `test.c` file with:

```
gcc -g -rdynamic ./test.c -o test
```

I get following error:

```
./test.c: In function ‘handler’:
./test.c:16: error: ‘STDERR_FILENO’ undeclared (first use in this function)
./test.c:16: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
./test.c:16: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

My includes are the same as in the original post code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

My machine is ubuntu 13.04. Am I missing some library or haven't included something?

Comment: Show what you are including in `test.c`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Also `#include <unistd.h>`.

See this [GNU documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Descriptors-and-Streams.html).