# Custom signal handlers with OpenCV debug mode

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to make an application that handles crashes on its own. I was able to find out how to handle SIGSEGV ([How to generate a stacktrace when my gcc C++ app crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes)) - but it seems like the OpenCV error handler comes into action whenever something goes wrong.

This causes my custom signal handler to never execute. Any hints on how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: this solution works on linux only**

It is possible to replace an action. But using the signal function won't do the job.

You have to use sigaction to replace the previous signal handler. Take a look:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html