# Programmatically get debug information

Tags: c++, debugging, c++11, debug-symbols

Using

```
#include <execinfo.h>
```

one can access methods for unwinding the stack, at least on a most linux configurations. However, this allows one to fetch a char * to some NTBS (null terminated byte string) which shows some information, but not all of it, especially not:

- file names
- line numbers
- function names

I have written a bash-script which can deduce a line number and a file using objdump and the text address of the instruction, however its use is tedious as I have to copy paste the address of multiple stack frames to it manually.

Given that g++ allows one to include debugging symbols with the -g command line option, how can I parse and access them in c++ programmatically? Debuggers like gdb and valgrind are also capable of accessing this information at runtime somehow: I'm assuming they use some library for that or if they implement it themselves export the functionality as an API. For example, valgrind defines some interesting function declarations in include/pub_tool_debuginfo.h. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything else. I created this as a starting point:

```cpp
#include <execinfo.h>

namespace stck {


class stacktrace_t {};

stacktrace_t stacktrace;

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, stacktrace_t) {
  out << "stacktrace:\n";

  size_t max = 256;
  void **stackframes = new void *[max];
  size_t numel;
  while ((numel = backtrace(stackframes, max)) >= max) {
    max *= 2;
    delete[] stackframes;
    stackframes = new void *[max];
  }

  char **symbols = backtrace_symbols(stackframes, numel);
  for(size_t i = 0; i < numel; ++i)
    out << symbols[i] << '\n';

  delete[] stackframes;
  return out;
}


}
```

source: http://ideone.com/RWoADT

Are there any suggestions to append this code to also output human readable debugging information?

As a note, I'm implementing this for usage with mex, a matlab compiler which uses g[++|cc]. Whenever I'm using the functionality, the program is in a 'good' state, that is an error is detected but noting really has has happened; like a segmentation fault.

For example, one could check if the argument of sqrt is non-negative, and if not use the stck::stacktrace to show where this happened.

### update

I think the information is not directly available at runtime (although I'm not sure), but is only available in the executable **file**, not in the executable **text** in memory. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Hence I think there is no way around parsing the executable **file**, for example via addre2line:

```cpp
namespace stck {

std::string getstackframe(char *frame) {
  std::string fr(frame);
  size_t loc0 = fr.find("(");
  size_t loc1 = fr.find(")");
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << "addr2line -e " << fr.substr(0, loc0) << " -pfC " << fr.substr(loc0 + 2, loc1 - loc0 - 2);

  FILE* pipe = popen(ss.str().c_str(), "r");
  char buffer[128];

  std::stringstream result;
  while(!feof(pipe))
    if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
      result << buffer;

  pclose(pipe);
  return result.str();
}

class stacktrace_t {};

stacktrace_t stacktrace;

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, stacktrace_t) {
  out << "stacktrace:\n";

  size_t max = 256;
  void **stackframes = new void *[max];
  size_t numel;
  while ((numel = backtrace(stackframes, max)) >= max) {
    max *= 2;
    delete[] stackframes;
    stackframes = new void *[max];
  }

  char **symbols = backtrace_symbols(stackframes, numel);
  for(size_t i = 0; i < numel; ++i)
    out << getstackframe(symbols[i]);

  out << '\n';

  delete[] stackframes;
  return out;
}


}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a stacktrace when my gcc C++ app crashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes)

Comment: Why can't you use the [`__FILE__`](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/__FILE__.html), [`__LINE__`](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/__LINE__.html), and the C++11 [`__func__`](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=338) (which also exist in other compiler-specific forms in older compilers)?

Comment: @Barry Could you point out where they specifically and programmatically get line numbers and file names? I could not find it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @MikaelPersson Because these are not usefull for stack-unwinding, they will just show me the information of the top stackframe: which is useless. The top stackframe will always be the operator<< in my case, hence I will always see the same result. I might use #define to define something that outputs them at the location where operator << is called, but (1) that still does not handle complete unwinding and (2) the use of #define is deprecated or at least bad style.

Comment: I suggest you research the *map* file.  This is a file generated during the linking phase which contains information about symbols in your program.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I'm assuming you are referring to the file created by gcc via -Xlinker -Map=output.map. Is a map file something that one can access at runtime or are you suggesting I learn about the ABI of my configuration and create parse methods myself?

Comment: Are you asking for run-time debug information or looking up symbolic information afterwards?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews run-time debug information.

Comment: Similar to (new Exception()).printStackTrace() in Java.