# Access cython stack inside python

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to get some information from inside long running cython functions (an ODE solver).

I've tried creating a signal handler which walks up the stack (using `frame.f_back`), but it appears this doesn't include cython frames.

Is it possible to access any cython frame from python?

Comment: in general this is way harder in C than python (and cython is C once it compiles). If this is *really* important to you, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes