# Testing with CppUnit, compiled with gcc, produce stack trace

Tags: c++, unit-testing, debugging, gcc, cppunit

I have a lot of C++ test-cases that are all implemented using the CppUnit unit testing framework.

In our project we have tons of statements in various test-classes and various helper classes - short - spread around the whole testing code - which all somewhere deep inside rely on the various **CPPUNIT_ASSERT_****** macros to ensure the results are as expected.

A typical helper function that is used during the testing framework might look like this:

```
void checkMatricesEqual(const Matrix& ref,const Matrix& val) {
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(ref.w,val.w);
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(ref.h,val.h);
    ...
    ...
}
```

Now, if an assertion fails, CppUnit prints out the name of the test function, and the file.cpp:line, which is not very helpful if it points to a general test helper function like the one above. In a big testing framework the location of an error can be hard to track down then.

Instead, I would really love to see a stack trace as output instead. 
I know that printing a stack trace from with some chunk of code using internal gcc libraries and -g is possible [How to generate a stacktrace when my gcc C++ app crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes).

What I don't know: How can one integrate this with CppUnit?
Create a patch and override the original CppUnit functionality?
Maybe somehow hook into the generation of messages?

If anyone has a hint how to accomplish something like this I would really appreciate.

Comment: Have you tried `CPPUNIT_ASSERT(ref.w == val.w)`?

Comment: not sure; how this would help here?

Comment: You would need to either add custom asserters or change the cppunit code. Cppunit itself does not provide such a feature as there is not cross-platform way to implement something like that in C++.

Comment: sad thing ok. I will see how I will handle it and post an answer if I have found a good way