# On Linux, backtrace_symbols_fd function doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, linux, dynamic, trace, segmentation-fault

I referred to this Stack Overflow question to test if [SIGSEGV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault#Overview) could be caught and processed:

*[How to automatically generate a stacktrace when my program crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes)*

#### File *h.cpp*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void handler(int sig) {
  void *array[10];
  size_t size = backtrace(array, 10);

  // Print out all the frames to stderr
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: signal %d:\n", sig);
  backtrace_symbols_fd(array, size, STDERR_FILENO);
  exit(1);
}

int main()
{
  int *foo = (int*)-1;  // Make a bad pointer
  printf("%d\n", *foo); // Causes a segmentation fault
}
```

I compile them:

```
gcc -rdynamic -g h.cpp && ./a.out
```

Result:

> Segmentation fault (core dump)

Well, it doesn't print out the call stack as I expected. Do I have to set up any system parameters?

Comment: you don't register signal handler use `signal(SIGSEGV, handler);` in the main function for install handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems.

1. A `SIGSEGV` handler is not registered using `sigaction()`.
2. Within the signal handler, `fprintf` is called. `fprintf` is not a reentrant library function, and it cannot be called from a signal handler. Especially for a `SIGSEGV` when, potentially, the entire heap has been nuked from high orbit, and `stderr`s, internal file buffer could be a smoking crater. Only system calls, like `write()` can be safely called from a signal handler.

Answer (score 1):

Change the *main* function like below:

```
int main()
{
   signal(SIGSEGV, handler);  // Register handler
   int *foo = (int*)-1;  // Make a bad pointer
   printf("%d\n", *foo);  // Causes a segmentation fault
}
```

Comment: `signal()` is obsolete. All new code should use `sigaction()`.