# Linux - segmentation fault only sometimes - how to debug

Tags: c++, c, linux, segmentation-fault

I have a Linux program, that from time to time ends with a segmentation fault. The program is running periodically every hour, but the segmentation fault occurs only sometimes.

I have a problem to debug this, because if I run the program again with the same input, no error is reported and all is OK.

Is there a way, how to "report" in which part of the code error occured or what caused the problem?

Comment: Print statements?

Comment: Run the program under `gdb`? Get a core dump? What have you tried?

Comment: Try to log variable states. Also, you could try to run it under `valgrind`.

Comment: @gowrath I have tried print statements, but it is a problem because error occured randomly. So I try to repair something, it runs fine afterwards, but the next day, crash again

Comment: @Yaeger there are reported no memory leaks

Comment: I am not talking about memory leaks @MartinPerry. If you compile your program with the "-g" option and run it through valgrind, it will give you a report about where (on which line number) a segmentation file occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your code not crashing every time, you can use `backtrace` as well. Using this you can see the `function call stack` at the time of crash. There are many examples available. In my projects I normally use the following code for backtracing.

```
/*
*   call reg_usr2 function from main
*   gcc -rdynamic myfile.c -o output
*/


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <execinfo.h>

#define FILE_NAME   "/tmp/debug"
#define MODE        0xFFFF

void dbgprint(int flag, char* fmt, ...)
{
    if(flag & MODE) {
        char buf[100];
        va_list vlist;
        FILE *fp = fopen(FILE_NAME,"a");
        va_start(vlist, fmt);
        vsnprintf( buf, sizeof( buf), fmt, vlist);
        va_end( vlist);
        fprintf(fp,"[%x]->%s\n", flag, buf);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}

/** Here is the code to print backtrace **/
void print_stack_trace ()
{
    void *array[20];
    size_t size;
    char **strings;
    size_t i;

    size = backtrace (array, 20);
    strings = backtrace_symbols (array, size);

    dbgprint(0xFFFF, "Obtained %zd stack frames.", size);
    dbgprint(0xFFFF, "-------------------------");
    dbgprint(0xFFFF, "---------Backtrace-------");

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        dbgprint (0xFFFF, "%s", strings[i]);
    dbgprint(0xFFFF, "-------------------------");

    free (strings);
}

void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(FILE_NAME,"a");
    if (signo == SIGUSR2){
        dbgprint(0xFFFF, "received SIGUSR2");
        dbgprint(0xFFFF, "----------------");
    }
    print_stack_trace();
    exit(0);
}

void reg_usr2()
{
    if (signal(SIGUSR2, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("\ncan't catch SIGUSR2\n");
}

int main()
{
    reg_usr2(); //should be first line of main after variables

    //Code.....

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: why you need it while core dump provides you backtrace.

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware of core dump. can you please give any link for it?

Comment: Thanks for your great information. But I am working in  a linux based machine which has no support of this. That is why I have only backtrace choice.

Comment: NO it is only for linux machine. see second answer which Ctx gave.

Comment: execinfo may not available on all linux based system such as android, also the program should be linked with -rdynamic

Answer (score 4):

The usual way is to have the crashing program generate a corefile and analyze this after the crash. Make sure, that:

- the maximum corefile-size is big enough (i.e. *unlimited*) by calling `ulimit -c unlimited` in the shell, which starts the process.
- The cwd is writable by the segfaulting process.

Then you can analyze the file with

`gdb <exe> <corefile>`

Comment: To generate corefile, do I have to "build" the program with some debug informations?

Comment: While it is helpful (compile with `-ggdb`), because the corefile contains more information then (for example to show the line number of the crashing source code line), it is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: @MartinPerry NO, you have to increase only process resource limit. Do run only on console what Ctx told. "ulimit -c unlimited"

Answer (score 3):

You can generate backtrace by catching SIGSEGV signal, and see where your application throw an invalid access.
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77336/4490542

But there is more easier solution, try running your application with catchsegv

> catchsegv './program args'

and better alternative, valgrind

> valgrind --tool=none ./program args