# common C library to install standard signal handler for SIGSEGV

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, backtrace, signal-handling

Is here any C library with a function like `install_default_signal_handlers()` which will install some default signal handler for SIGSEGV and related signals, where the signal handler will print a backtrace?
The signal handler, and also the installation of the signal handler should be provided by the library.

I think [backward-cpp](https://github.com/bombela/backward-cpp) does it for C++ with `backward::SignalHandling sh;`.

There is also [Google Breakpad](https://chromium.googlesource.com/breakpad/breakpad) but this might be overkill.

There is [libSegFault](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6599348/133374) which seems to do that but it only seems to be available on some Unixes (part of GlibC, and there is a FreeBSD implementation), not on MacOSX.

Some related discussion is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes) but this discusses mostly the code to print the backtrace but I search for a library which provides the signal handler for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's no default handler installed for SIGSEGV on any of the *nix systems. But you can 1) install one yourself, 2) print the backtrace and 3) then exit.
The "exit" part is required becuase, it's *undefined* to return from their handler (if one is installed) for some signals; `SIGSEGV` is one of them.

The tricky part is (2) - printing the backtrace. [Glibc provides 3 interfaces](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html): `backtrace`, `backtrace_symbols` and `backtrace_symbols_fd`.
You can use whichever is suitable and print the stack trace.

If you are *not* using Glibc then you may have to do more work. For example, you can use `_Unwind_Backtrace` which is available on systems using gcc (not necessarily Glibc).

Comment: Yes I know that I can done that myself. But I'm searching for a library which does it for me. Not the printing, I know that there is `backtrace`, but even the installation and the signal handler itself.

Comment: There's no standard library function; anything you'd use would involve non-standard functions/extensions. Even the backward-cpp you linked to uses `_Unwind_Backtrace` which is probably your best bet if whatever libc you are using doesn't already provide something like Glibc's `backtrace`.

Comment: That's why I'm searching for some library. So you say no-one thought that it might be useful to make such a library? But for C++, there is (backward-cpp). I don't care how the library implements it. It's fine if the support on some platforms is limited. Just a simple `backtrace()` lib would be fine for me.