# Segmentation fault when executed from linux command line

Tags: c, linux, gcc, clion

My code compiles and runs fine in my IDE.
However, when I use gcc to compile and then run my a.out file it says Segmentation fault (core dumped).

(edited to include my code)

In main.c I have commented out all of my code and it still causes seg fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>


#include "BmpProcessor.h"
#include "PixelProcessor.h"
#include "PpmProcessor.h"
#include "debug.h"

#define THREAD_COUNT 8;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

/** commented out all of my code */
    
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas why? None of my other files that I include have a main method.

DEBUGGING DETAILS

```
gcc -g -Wall -pedantic -o PurdyImageProcessor PurdyImageProcessor.c BmpProcessor.c PpmProcessor.c PixelProcessor.c -lm -pthread
PixelProcessor.c: In function ‘boxBlurMultithreading’:
PixelProcessor.c:437:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
PixelProcessor.c: In function ‘cheesifyMultithreading’:
PixelProcessor.c:487:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
```

Comment: You've given us NO information relevant to your program.  Most likely you're triggering undefined behavior, but there's no way to know for sure without seeing the code.  Also, try running your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: You probably have undefined behavior that express itself by using a different compiler.  Here is how to trouble shoot it.  Compile your program with debugging symbols (i.e. -g2) then `ulimit -c unlimited` to get a core file next time you run it.  Then analyze the core file with `gdb binary core`  Or, as @CharlesDuffy points out, after you compile the binary with debugging symbols run it under gdb with: `gdb binary` or you attach to it's pid if you have the opportunity before it crashes.

Comment: Don't need a core dump if you attach a debugger during initial execution.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah, good point, and it gives you a live process.  Not used to that luxury.

Comment: Updated with my debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need more information.  Please do the following:

1. Recompile with "-g", for debugging information.  Include "-Wall -pedantic" for additional compiler warnings

   EXAMPLE: `gcc -g -Wall -pedantic -o myprog myprog.c`
2. Update your post with your "gcc" command, and the compiler warnings you get.
3. Run your program.  If it still crashes, use [gdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/) to analyze further:

   EXAMPLE: `gdb ./myprog`  Type "r" to execute.  Type "bt" to get a stack trace after it crashes.  Copy/paste the stack trace into your post.

Here are several useful links:

- [GNU Debugger Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gnu_debugger/index.htm)
- [How to automatically generate a stacktrace when my program crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77336/421195)
- [Debugging Segmentation Faults and Pointer Problems](https://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/segfaults.html)

Comment: Updated! Two warnings appear. Are those what could be causing the issue?

Comment: This information helped me out. Thank you so much! Appreciate it.