# How to simply create a C++ stacktrace dump on crash on Windows

Tags: c++, crash, stack-trace

I'm not looking for anything other than logging a stacktrace to a file when the program crashes. I don't care for it to email me or upload anything to a server. It's fine for the moment if that means it only works for `RelWithDebInfo` builds, or for builds with access to `.pdb` files or whatever. How can I accomplish this?

I'm looking for, in addition to library recommendations, an understanding of what actually needs to be done (many different libraries/solutions seem to have a pretty complex web of requirements depending on OS, etc.).

Some finer grained questions (specifically for C++ on Windows):

- do I need to boot my process *from a different process*, so the different process can ultimately do the logging on crash?
- how do I "catch" the error in the first place?
- what compilation mode does my program need to be in?
- do I need debug symbols shipped alongside the executable?

I'm looking for "how do I do this" - not "what libraries assist in doing this".

Comment: Are the Windows portions of [How to automatically generate a stacktrace when my program crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-automatically-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-program-crashes) any help?

Comment: @user4581301 unfortunately no- or at least, not yet. I'm trying to use WER, but it requires setting up a microsoft partnership, and I'm waiting on that to go through. so I'm sitting on my hands until that's done. and even then, see edit (regarding "now what do I have to _do_?")

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minidumpapiset/nf-minidumpapiset-minidumpwritedump) from dbghelp.dll.

Comment: see post edit re: "what do I have to _do_?"

Comment: For catching the _errors_ I think you're referring to the Win32 exceptions (like access violations, division by zero etc.) which can be handled by setting [SE Translator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-se-translator?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170). You must use /EHa when using _set_se_translator and to log the stacktrace you don't need the debug symbols, MiniDumpWriteDump works in release.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not looking for anything other than logging a stacktrace to a file when the program crashes.

Use Ian Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace).

It is ported to several OSes. On Linux, it works better if executables and libraries are compiled with DWARF debug information. (e.g. with `g++ -Wall -g -O2` if using recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Be also aware of [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) on Linux.

[RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) uses it. And so does recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compilers in 2021.