# How to redefine the template class constructor via a macro in C++11?

Tags: c++

I want to recorded the line which created the shared_ptr in **C++ 11**.
Here is my way to rewrite shared_ptr as Shared_ptr :

```
template<class T>
class Shared_Ptr{
public:
    Shared_Ptr(T* ptr = nullptr,int line=__LINE__)
        :_pPtr(ptr)
        , _pRefCount(new int(1))
        , _pMutex(new mutex)
    {
        cout<<this<<"is located in "<<line<<endl;
    }
    ~Shared_Ptr()
    {
        Release();
        cout<<this<<endl;
    }
    Shared_Ptr(const Shared_Ptr<T>& sp)
        :_pPtr(sp._pPtr)
        , _pRefCount(sp._pRefCount)
        , _pMutex(sp._pMutex)
    {
        AddRefCount();
    }
    Shared_Ptr<T>& operator=(const Shared_Ptr<T>& sp)
    {
        //if (this != &sp)
        if (_pPtr != sp._pPtr)
        {
            Release();
            _pPtr = sp._pPtr;
            _pRefCount = sp._pRefCount;
            _pMutex = sp._pMutex;
            AddRefCount();
        }
        return *this;
    }
    T& operator*(){
        return *_pPtr;
    }
    T* operator->(){
        return _pPtr;
    }
    int UseCount() { return *_pRefCount; }
    T* Get() { return _pPtr; }
    void AddRefCount()
    {
        _pMutex->lock();
        ++(*_pRefCount);
        _pMutex->unlock();
    }

    
private:
    void Release()
    {
        bool deleteflag = false;
        _pMutex->lock();
        if (--(*_pRefCount) == 0)
        {
            delete _pRefCount;
            delete _pPtr;
            deleteflag = true;
        }
        _pMutex->unlock();
        if (deleteflag == true)
            delete _pMutex;
    }
private:
    int *_pRefCount;
    T* _pPtr;
    mutex* _pMutex;
};
```

```
class student
{
int age;
public:
  student(int a):age(a)
  {

  }
}
;
int main()
{
   Shared_ptr<student> Tom(new student(24),__LINE__);
}
```

Is there a way to make  `Shared_ptr<student>Tom(new student(24))` as same as `Shared_ptr <student> Tom(new student(24),__ LINE__)` in C++11? In other words , invoke class Constructor with the arguments bound to args.

I tried to use marco to achieve,but I don't know the correct way **how to** **define the macro of template class constructor**.

Below is the macro definition I tried to write but wrong

```
template<typename T>
#define Shared_ptr<T>::Shared_ptr(T*) Shared_ptr<T>::Shared_ptr(T * ,__LINE__)
```

Comment: please show your attempt. Make it a [mcve]

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: didn't the OP show his attempt ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust OP is asking how to use a macro and says they tried to use one. There is no such macro in the posted code

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: should he add a line such as `#define MyMacro No idea how to do that` ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust no they should show what they tried, just what they did already

Comment: [For C++ 20 using source_location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67971576/12002570). Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67970107/12002570) where `__builtin_LINE()` is used.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: we probably didn't see the same versions of the post.

Comment: I want to know which line owns the shared_ptr which is causing the object to not be destructed.

Comment: @user17732522 I think OP has added the code for `Shared_ptr`.

Comment: With the code you are showing now `Shared_ptr<student> Tom(24);` doesn't work in the first place, so it is hard to follow what you want.

Comment: If you have a memory leak and need to figure out where it comes from, you should use an external debugging tool. For example valgrind or the address sanitizer (ASAN) which includes a leak detector. There are other leak detectors as well.

Comment: Sorry, the code is error. I have corrected it already.

Comment: My problem is not a memory leak. my problem is like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061634/how-do-i-know-who-holds-the-shared-ptr. I want to find which line has the object shared_ptr which is causing the object to not be destructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `int line=__LINE__` in constructor parameters with `int line = __builtin_LINE()`. It's a non-standard compiler extension, but it works at least in GCC, Clang, and MSVC (i.e. most common compilers).

Then `Shared_ptr<student> Tom(nullptr);` will work.

---

`Shared_ptr<student> Tom(42);` will not work, because `Shared_ptr` doesn't have the right constructor, but it has nothing to do with getting the line number.

Comment: Sorry , the old code Shared_ptr<student> Tom(24); is wrong . It should be Shared_ptr<student> Tom(new student(24));

Comment: I tried `int line = __builtin_LINE()`. it worked. Thanks